# Vector iterator not dereferencable with std::shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble dereferencing a found `shared_ptr` from a `vector` after `std::find`. Could someone explain why this is the case?

```
    extern std::vector< shared_ptr<King::Actor> > selected
    foo(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>> &playerUnits)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>>::const_iterator result;
        result = std::find(std::begin(playerUnits), std::end(playerUnits), selected.back());

        if (result != std::end(playerUnits))
            return *std::next(result); // found
        return nullptr;
    }
enter code here
```

closest answer is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301959/vector-iterator-not-dereferencable#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301959/vector-iterator-not-dereferencable#_=_)
I believe it both found it and not the end of the vector, yet it still reports not dereferencable.

Comment: What is your error? Compiler error? Runtime? What is the exact message you had?

Comment: If the found unit is the last one, then you try to dereference off the end

Comment: The example you have given would not compile, since the return type of `foo()` is invalid.    In any event, the problem would not be that an iterator is not dereferencable.   It is probably that dereferencing `std::next(result)` gives a result that cannot be converted to the function's return type.     You will also find that returning `result` would not compile for the same reason.   Whatever that type actually is in your code .....

Comment: I'm not sure why you are returning `*next(result)` instead of `*result`?

Comment: @StevenW.Klassen his MVCE doesn't give all the details but he probably wants the next one. However, should the container be cyclic, he must check if he reached the element before last in which case the next result should return `std::begin(playerUnits)`.

Comment: @Peter this is a runtime error message, the problem you suggest would be a compilation error

Comment: @M.M thanks.  The check I put in for std::end is needed for std::next before dereferencing.  The run time error is when the next one is the end.

Comment: @Chris maybe you mistakenly think that `std::end` means the last element?

Comment: @M.M yes, I did think that.  Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if (result != std::end(playerUnits))
        return *std::next(result); // found
```

if the found result is the last one, `std::next` produces `end`, which you then dereference.