# Getting byte value from char

Tags: c++, char, byte

It simple but I am getting problem with this.
http://www.ipix.lt/images/90928843.png
I want to cout buffer[5]. But not the symbol value, but 255. Tried typecasting to int or byte but that gets -1.

Comment: yeah, its not implemented yet. the point is to print buffer[5] as 255. or assign buffer to int as 255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct that, casting it to int, you get -1, because `char` in your implementation is a signed type (it's actually implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned, and usually you can change it in the compiler options); what you see in the debugger window is it's unsigned representation.

To get its unsigned value you should first cast it to `unsigned char` and then to `unsigned int` (I think you could also get away with just casting it to `unsigned int`, but I'm not sure).

---EDIT---

Actually in the debugger window I see its type as `unsigned char`, so the first part of my answer may not apply... you should tell us how is that buffer defined.

Comment: its just char buffer[size];
and you were right in that first part. casting it twice works. but casting it just to unsigned int gets -1.

Answer (score 1):

How is `byte` defined? C++ knows no such type.

You can cast to `int` however:

```
static_cast<int>(msg.buffer[i + 2]) …
```

Note the use of `static_cast` instead of the deprecated C-style casts. Always use the former, never the latter. For explanation on why, see the question on [C++ cast syntax style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168/1968).

(Adding to that, Matteo is right in that you need to cast to an unsigned value first.)

Comment: @gemexas: correct, look at Matteo’s answer for an explanation why that is and how to fix it. Although this **should** work for `unsigned char` …

Answer (score 0):

Using stringstream (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) would be one viable solution, converting the byte (Which, I imagine is just an unsigned char) to an integer stored as a string.