# What is the difference between C-like casting and functional casting?

Tags: c++, casting

Consider:

```
b = (int) a;    // C-like cast notation
b = int (a);    // Functional notation
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles

Answer (score 8):

Apparently I was wrong in my initial cut at an answer.  They are roughly equivalent.  And while compound type names like `long long` or `void *` can't use functional syntax directly (i.e. `long long(val)` doesn't work), using `typedef` can get around this issue.

Both cast notations are very bad and should be avoided.  For example:

```
const char c = 'a';
void *fred = (void *)(&c);
```

works, and it shouldn't.

Both the C-style cast notation will sometimes behave like `static_cast`, sometimes like `const_cast`, sometimes like `reinterpret_cast`, or even a combination of the two depending on the exact situation in which it's used.  These semantics are rather complex and it's not always easy to tell exactly what's happening in any given situation.

I have gone to using mostly C++ `static_cast<type>(val)` style casts, and never use C-style casts.  Based on my research for this question I'm going to also stop using function-style casts for anything.  The question "[C++ cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)" has an excellent answer (the accepted one) that details why.

Comment: This is completely false. `class A { operator int() const; }; int test( A a ) { return int(a); }` works perfectly even though `int` has no constructor. A function style cast with a single parameter has exactly the same effect as the equivalent C-style cast.

Comment: @Charles Bailey - I read more and found out I was wrong.  :-)  I fixed my answer.

Comment: Functional style cast with pointers: `typedef void * voidp;  voidp fred = voidp(&c);`

Comment: @PigBen - Oh, you're right.  *sigh*  Fixed my answer yet again.  I hate when people use typedefs to obscure the fact a type is a pointer.  :-(

Comment: @Omnifarious: I do too.  I was just showing a way the cast could be done.

Comment: @PigBen - *nod*  I realize.  I was explaining why I didn't think of it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any difference. It is a matter of preference. These are old-style casts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you use it and how. I.e. if you have values or pointers (or pointers of pointers).

With C++ you should read up on *_cast<> and use them instead.