# Casting to an unsigned char

Tags: c, types, casting

I'm using MPLab C18 C compiler and getting a syntax error with this code:

```
hundreds = unsigned char((tick / 100));
tens = unsigned char((tick - (hundreds * 100)) / 10);
ones = unsigned char((tick - (hundreds * 100) - (tens * 10)));
```

`tick` is an `unsigned int`.
What I'm attempting is to convert a three digit value over to three individual ASCII values by means of simple division and casting the whole number into my `unsigned char` variables.

It looks okay to me but I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: that is the C++ casting style, it will not work in C.

Comment: I don't think that works with multiple token simple-type-specifiers even in C++.

Comment: This won't work for C. Guess, in C++ this type of syntax works, considering copy constructor behavoir.

Comment: No, doesn't work in C++, and wouldn't involve a copy constructor if it did.

Comment: Right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775781/what-is-the-difference-between-c-like-casting-functional-casting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Casting is done in parentheses:

```
 hundreds = (unsigned char)(tick/100);
```