# parenthesis of method call

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am wondering are the following code the same:

```
//first
string str; int num;
stringstream(str)>>num;
//second
string str; int num;
(stringstream)str>>num;
```

I tried to run them and they work. Can you tell me that's the difference between them? Or they're the same? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Check here for a good explanation of the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles

Answer (score 4):

As [Luchian Grigore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790576/1139697) already told you they're equivalent.

The first one will use the `stringstream::stringstream(const string&)` constructor to create a temporary object. The second one is a C-style typecast, which is essentially the same as `static_cast<stringstream>(str) >> num;`. The `static_cast<>` will use the constructor above, so both are equivalent.

However, as Luchian already told you, you shouldn't use C-style typecasts. Use `static_cast<>` instead.

See also:

- [Why use static_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)
- [CPP: Type casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial%20%20/typecasting/)

Comment: I thought I covered this: "The static_cast<> will use the constructor above, so both are equivalent". On the other hand, it's late and I could be missing something...

Comment: No, it's late and I missed it. :) +1 for a better explanation.

Comment: Why not just call the constructor directly? Are there any benefits to cast(either in c or c++ style)? I mean just for thiscase. @Luchian

Comment: @Gao the cast also calls the constructor. The only difference is in style. The two do exactly the same thing.