# C++11 enum class instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, construction, enum-class

I've encountered the following form of enum class variable instantiation and it is compiling without any warning or error under VS2012:

```
UINT32 id;
enum class X {apple, pear, orange};
X myX = X(id);
```

Moreover, sending `X(id)` as an argument to a function expecting X type param compiled as well.
I'm not sure if the result is always correct or it's just a strange compiler behavior.

However, trying to do `X myX(id);` instead of the above resulted in compilation error:

> > error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'UINT32' to 'X'.
> >     Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast,C-style cast or function-style cast).

Reading the C++11 standard didn't help me to understand.
So I have 2 questions on this subject:

1. Is it possible to construct an enum class object with integral type as a parameter?
2. If 1 is true, why `X myX(id)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not constructing an enum with that syntax. Instead you are using an alternative explicit cast syntax to cast from `UINT32` to `enum class X`. For example it is possible to explicitly cast a double to an int like this:

```
double p = 0.0;
int f = int(p)
```

See [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles) for all the various cast syntax you can use in c++.

Your code can equivalently be written with the more common cast syntax like this:

```
UINT32 id;
enum class X {apple, pear, orange};
X myX = (X)id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this syntax. But this raises another question: how can I know if such syntax will result in casting or in calling a constructor of class X?

Comment: @icepack: In order to call the constructor of class `X`, `X` must first *be a class*. `X` is a strongly-typed enum, which is not a class (despite using the word `class` in its definition). When you're using `classname(stuff)`, you'll always get constructor calling.

Comment: I'm aware of that. My last question is more general and relates to a situation when X is actually a class. In other cases there is naturally no ambiguity. So what you're saying is that this casting syntax is not applicable to classes.

Comment: @ildjarn that is not correct. static cast is a different beast than the first former two (c style casts), assuming you are talking about nonclass types.

Comment: (talking about class types, the first two are still equivalent but can hardly be called "c style").