# Assigning values after defining an enumeration

Tags: c++, enums, assign, enum-class

I'm a newbie to C++ and especially C++11, so since I've now got to use it, a few questions about 'enum' and 'enum class' came up:

**Can I assign values after the enumeration has been declared?**

```
enum MyEnum;
MyEnum::HELLO = 0;
MyEnum::WORLD = 1;
```

**Can I assign values to a number? (ex.: Myenum::0 = 2)**

```
enum MyEnum;
MyEnum::0 = 16;
MyEnum::1 = 24;
MyEnum::3 = 64;
```

**How does enum class work when using a struct or class as the underlying type?**

Would the entries in the enumeration be valid instances of the struct/class?

```
class Test {
    private int v = 0;
    Test(int v) {
        this->v = v;
    }
};

enum class MyEnum : Test {
    Test0 = new Test(0),
    Test1 = new Test(1),
};
```

I found these links when I searched for the topic:

- http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum
- [Do we really need "enum class" in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936030/do-we-really-need-enum-class-in-c11)
- [C++11 enum class instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957499/c11-enum-class-instantiation)

Which, as you can see, left a few questions.

Comment: Here's another one, more general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041711/whats-an-enum-class-and-why-should-i-care/14042083#14042083

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot do any of those.

However, you may provide the *definition* the enum after its *declaration* as:

```
enum MyEnum; //declaration

enum MyEnum  //definition
{
  HELLO = 0,
  WORLD = 1;
};
```

---

> Can I assign values to a number?

No. That doesn't make sense. A number already has a *value*. It is constant.

---

Please get an introductory book on programming in C++. Here are few recommendations :

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Ok, so that clears up most of the questions I have. the only one remaining is: Why doesn't GCC pick this up as being wrong?
All of the above examples compile fine with my copy of the GCC compiler (using -w -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -Wall -Wmain -std=c++11), I'm not sure if they however run fine.

Comment: None of them will compile. Post your code here. http://www.ideone.com and give me the link. I wanna see it myself.

Comment: My Error, I just forgot to include the file (so used to that being done automatically from BlitzMax and BlIde). Now it doesn't compile with an error :).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot *ever* assign to a value in C++. The following is illegal:

```
42 = 23;
```

And for pretty much the same reason you cannot assign the value of an enum either.

Furthermore, you cannot even *use* the values of an enum after its declaration (i.e. you cannot write `auto x = enum_name::name;`), only after *definition*. You can only use the enum’s name.

> Can I assign values to a number?

I’m not sure what this is supposed to mean but apart from what I’ve said before that syntax is illegal anyway. That is, you cannot access the second enum value by writing `enum_name::1`.

> How does enum class work when using a struct or class as the underlying type?

You cannot use custom types as underlying types, only built-in integral types.

Comment: The 'Can I assign a value to a number' was meant, that the 'key' for the enumeration is numeric (e.g. '4'), so that it would be accessible via MyEnum::4. But I guess that is not possible, so I'll have to find another way of listing entries by their Id.

Comment: @Xaymar Yes, enumeration keys must be valid identifiers so they cannot be numeric.