# (string)char typecast

Tags: c++, string, casting, char

I want to cast a char to a string with this function:

```
int charIndexDistance (char a, char b)
{
    if (indexical) {
        string test_a = convertOntology((string)a, 0);
        string test_b = convertOntology((string)b, 0);
        cout << test_a << " " << test_b << endl;

        int test = abs(char_index[a] - char_index[b]);
        return test; //measure indexical distance between chars
    } else 
        return 1;
}
```

but I get this "error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'std::string"

what is thr problem? and how is a char cast to a string - should I use string append?

also, the `cout` and `int test` are for debugging purposes and will be removed later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There simply is no such conversion. Instead, you have to construct a string manually:

```
string(1, a)
```

This uses the [constructor taking a length and a `char` to fill the string with](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

In the context of your code:

```
string test_a = convertOntology(string(1, a), 0);
string test_b = convertOntology(string(1, b), 0);
```

Even if an appropriate constructor / cast existed your code would be bad since [you should avoid C-style casts in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224/1968). The situation would call for a `static_cast` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is not a string.

A `char` is also not a null-terminated string.

A null-terminated string is a char array with the null character at the end.

Comment: so I could have done something like `char a; string a_test = 'a' + '\n'`

Comment: @forest No, since adding two `char`s doesn’t concatenate them, it adds their byte value. But you can concatenate an (empty) string and a `char`: `string() + 'a'` works (but is probably less efficient than my code). Note that `"" + 'a'` does *not* work, since `""` is *not* a string, it’s a null-terminated `char` array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(string)a` with `string(1,a)`

Answer (score 0):

Everything already mentioned works, but you may also want to try:

```cpp
char mychar = 'A';
string single_char = "";
string += mychar;
```

Hope that helps!