# What is the meaning of int(expr) in C++?

Tags: c++

When looking over some code from a friend's project, I recently saw syntax that looked like this.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<< int(32.5/5)  << std::endl;
}
```

When you run the above code, you get `6`, which is the expected value if the use of `int` functions like a cast.

However, I have never seen this syntax before and I could not find documentation for it on the web. I also did an experiment and noticed that this syntax is not valid in `C`.

Can someone explain the meaning of this syntax with documentation references?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial **or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: This is just another syntax for a cast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles

Comment: @nhgrif: Geebus. Do not be such.......

Comment: Is it actually a different syntax for cast or a constructor call?

Comment: This question is asking for link only answers which also aren't acceptable to post.  How can a question which can only be answered with unacceptable answers be on topic?

Comment: @nhgrif, If you copy the proper documentation into an answer, it is no longer a link-only request.

Comment: I'm very surprised to see a question like this from a 22.9k user. Surely you know how SO works, by now?

Comment: @wilx: Such _what_? He's right. He's literally quoting from the site rules.

Comment: @gnidmoo: Please do not write answers as comments. Write answers as _answers_.

Comment: @GregoryPakosz: Quite obviously not.

Comment: @Codor that's the advantage of this notation : same syntax for built-in types and object constructors. Extra handy in template code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a constructor call or a "function". There is no "int function".

This is *functional cast notation*; [it's just a cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

It's the same as `(int)(32.5/5)` (in this particular case).

And, no, C does not have it.

Comment: I think the fact that you could write a reasonable answer to this question implies that it is not exactly a terrible fit for our format. I agree that I could have phrased it better but you understood the intent fairly clearly.

Comment: @merlin2011: Actually I was a bit naughty, because I did not answer your question (which _is_ a bad fit) but some imaginary modified version of your question! But, yes, I gave you the benefit of the doubt. Now perhaps you can edit the question to make it fit the site's model, retaining your intent..?

Comment: I have edited the question. Let me know if the edit is up to scratch. :)

Comment: Adding to this a bit, the same syntax can involve a constructor call depending on the type. For example if `T` is a template parameter then `T(32.5/5);` is valid, and instantiating with a class type will call a constructor, and instantiating with `int` won't.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Right, but that's a factor of how explicit conversions work, not of what this syntax specifically does. If you catch my drift.