# Casting to void (not pointer) is allowed, why?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Why can I cast this vector to a void (not even a pointer)?

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a;
   (void)a;
}
```

How come this is allowed?

Comment: This is a discarded-value expression. It discards the value. By the way, don't use C-style casts.

Comment: It is a common way (but not the better) to remove warning about unused variable.

Comment: I don't know why it is allowed but I sometimes use it to prevent *variable not used* compiler warnings.

Comment: Any chance to get a standard quote?

Comment: it's used very commonly to suppress warnings on unused function parameters

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Casting to void simply discards the result of the expression. Sometimes, you'll see people using this to avoid "unused variable" or "ignored return value" warnings.

In C++, you should probably write `static_cast<void>(expr);` rather than `(void)expr;`

This has the same effect of discarding the value, while making it clear what kind of conversion is being performed.

The standard says:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void, in which
>   case it becomes a discarded-value expression (Clause 5). [ Note:
>   however, if the value is in a temporary object (12.2), the destructor
>   for that object is not executed until the usual time, and the value of
>   the object is preserved for the purpose of executing the destructor.
>   —end note ]

*ISO/IEC 14882:2011 5.2.9 par. 6*

Comment: What is ambiguous about `(void)expr;`? Is it just because _Don't use C-casts_ or is there an actual reason to avoid the C-cast version?

Comment: @nwp - just the usual [reasons to avoid C-style casts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224/3852968). Nothing special about casting to void.

Comment: But none of the usual reasons apply here. There is no conversion taking place so the kind of conversion doesn't even make sense. There is no reason to search for the cast since it doesn't do anything besides shutting up a compiler warning. There is no masking of weak code. This is just following the rules for the rule's sake, not for a purpose.

Comment: Using `static_cast` is rather awkward, the syntax `(void)` is much better imo. And there's no difference between them.

Comment: Still a good idea to confirm to new C++ standards in the case of the older standards becoming deprecated.

Comment: @nwp, @black: That's entirely a matter of style. I don't want to get into a debate on style here. `static_cast<void>` and `(void)` both work, and yes, the usual reasons don't really fit strongly here. I prefer to use C++ named casts everywhere, that's all.