# Should I use shared_ptr<Object> myObject = (shared_ptr<Object>) new Object() to access private constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr

I am working with a code base which makes extensive use of the following syntax:

```
shared_ptr<Object> myObject = (shared_ptr<Object>) new Object();
```

I noticed that I cannot access private constructors with `make_shared`, but `shared_ptr<Object> myObject = (shared_ptr<Object>) new Object();` works just fine. Should I be using it just because it seems to work? Are there any dangers? How is it different than `make_shared`?

I am aware of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c) question, which makes comparisons between `make_shared` and:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo"));
```

but I haven't been able to find a reference to the syntax I came across. Is it different, or is it the same as the above?

Comment: The 1st line of code looks like a `C` style cast: see (1) in here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`make_shared` allocates the object in the same block of memory as the control block.  This improves cache coherency and cuts out an allocation.

One way to permit `make_shared` to do this is to have a *private token* within your class, and a *public constructor* that consumes that token.

```
class Object {
private:
  struct token_t{ private: token_t() {}; friend class Object; };
  static token_t token() { return {}; }
  Object() = default;
public:
  Object( token_t ):Object() {}
};
```

now we can `make_shared<Object>( Object::token() )`.

This gives us one allocation, and doesn't violate the privacy of the construction as only things with access to private fields of `Object` can call that constructor.  They can, however, pass the token to another function (like `make_shared`) and it in turn can call the constructor in question.  This works with more arguments, naturally.

As for your syntax:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> myObject = (std::shared_ptr<Object>) new Object();
```

`(std::shared_ptr<Object>) new Object();` simply explicitly constructs a `shared_ptr<Object>` from `new Object()`.  It is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object)`.

We then take this prvalue and construct `myObject` from it.  In C++03 11 and 14, this copy/move construction is elided.  In C++17, the prvalue "construction instructions" are directly applied to `myObject`.  In practice, this results in the same machine code (unless you are a fool and explicitly tell your compiler to not elide construction).

In short, it works.  The only downside is the double-allocation of the separate control-block from the `Object` allocation.

Comment: I get an error... The way it is the `token()` function is private... so it cannot be used in the `make_shared<>()` call.

Comment: @alexis the point is that make shared can only be called with a token in a context that you have access to private data from the class (or where you are granted oermission by proxy by them passing you a token from such a context).  Simply make the constructor public if you do not want access control on it at all.  Ie suppose `static std::shared_ptr<Class> Class::make(){ return std::make_shared<Class>( token() ); }`