# What is the meaning of an expression with the form (type) (value)?

Tags: c++, variables, casting, arduino

I have this line:

```
lsb = (char) (intNumber & 0xff);
```

and I'm confused as to why is it written like

```
name = (type) (value)
```

What does it exactly mean, or what is the purpose of defining a variable like that?

Comment: Arduino is programmed in C++.

Comment: And to help you with the question, please [get a couple of good beginners books to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: That looks like a cast to me.

Comment: That doesn’t define a variable.

Comment: It's not a definition. It's a so called cast operation. The variable `intNumber` is bitwise ANDed with the literal number `0xff`. The result of this operation is converted to type `char` and assigned to the variable `lsb`.

Comment: The variable definition is elsewere in the code. It should look something like `type name`. What you posted is assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: First, no variable is defined in the code you show; the line is not a definition. Second, you are looking at a [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: Until you get a book that covers this basic syntax, read [C++ cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsb = (char) (intNumber & 0xff);`
intNumber has been **and**-ed with `0x11111111` and subsequently typecast to 8-bit character, hence it finds the least significant byte of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

That is the syntax to typecast a variable
e.g.:

```
float x = 5.55;
int y = (int)x; // in this case, the casting would have happened implicitly
// or 
printf("%d",(int)x);
// this will display 5
```

Here by specifying constant/variable will be converted to whatever type you mention inside your first pair of brackets.

Comment: It is **a** syntax for casting, among several - specifically, it's the *old* syntax to cast, inherited from C. Proper C++ code should really use one of the specific C++ casts.

Answer (score 0):

That line means you are casting the result given by the expression on the right forcing it to become a char, in order to fit the variable on the left.