# (C++) What are the Differences between these 3 type conversion methods?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Either of below methods gives me the same value when I use it on a char type variable. So what are the differences between them?

- `(int)c`
- `int{c}`
- `static_cast<int>(c)`

Comment: Did you read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)? Did you read the C++11 draft standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)? Did you read the documentation of your C++ compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)  ? Did you look into some [C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) ?

Comment: In practice, in most cases (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) at least), the generated machine code would be *exactly* the same. Try playing with `g++ -fverbose-asm -O -S` then look into the generated assembler code

Comment: gotta be a dupe, e.g. of [C++ cast syntax styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168/c-cast-syntax-styles)

Answer (score 2):

For starters using eth functional notation of casting requires s simple type specifier.

That is you may not for example write

```
unsigned int( c )
```

The functional notation of a casting creates a temporary object.

While using the explicit type conversion you may create for example an lvalue reference.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c = 'A';

    ++( char &)c;

    std::cout << "c = " << c << '\n';
}
```

From the C++ Standard (5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)

> 3 Similarly, a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by
> a braced-init-list creates a temporary object of the specified type
> direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified braced-init-list,
> and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

As for `static_cast` then accoding to the C++ Standard (5.2.9 Static cast)

> 1 The result of the expression static_cast(v) is the result of
> converting the expression v to type T. If T is an lvalue reference
> type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is an lvalue;
> if T is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is an xvalue;
> otherwise, the result is a prvalue. The static_cast operator shall not
> cast away constness