# Forward declaring a function that uses enable_if : ambiguous call

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, ambiguity, enable-if

I have some trouble forward declaring a function that uses [`boost::enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html): the following piece of code gives me a compiler error:

```
// Declaration
template <typename T>
void foo(T t);

// Definition
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(12);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I get an "ambiguous call to foo" error. According to the definition of `enable_if`, the 'type' typedef corresponds to `void` when the condition is true, so as far as I can see, the two signatures of `foo` match. Why does the compiler think they are different, and is there a correct way to forward declare `foo` (preferably without repeating the `enable_if` part)?

Comment: The match is the problem, the compiler can't decide which template you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not only a problem with enable_if. You get the same error on Visual Studio and gcc with the following code:

```
struct TypeVoid {
  typedef void type;
};

template<typename T>
void f();

template<typename T>
typename T::type f() {
}

int main()
{
  f<TypeVoid>();
  return 0;
}
```

I think the main problem is that the return type (before instantiation) is part of the signature of a template function. There is more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature).

Regarding your code, if the declaration refers to the definition, you should match both:

```
// Declaration       
template <typename T>       
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t);       

// Definition       
template <typename T>       
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t)       
{       
}
```

If the declaration refers to a different function, the compiler would never be able to choose the correct one for *int*s, because they both are valid. However, you can disable the first one for *int*s using *disable_if*:

```
// Other function declaration
template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t);

// Defition
template <typename T>       
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t)       
{       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the declaration and the definition do not match.

The solution is that the declaration should contain the exact same signature, and the the `enable_if` bit.

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

// Declaration
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t);

// Definition
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, int> >::type foo(T t)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo(12);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine on VC2008.