# Calling a function with a non-const pointer reolves to a template function over a function taking a pointer to const

Tags: c++

The following code was compiled on g++ 4.1.2 and g++ 4.4.4.  Both give the results noted in the comments.

```
int f(const int * a)
{
   return 0;
}

template<typename A>
int f(A a)
{
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    // return f(&x); // returns 1
    return f((const int *)&x); // returns 0
}
```

It appears to boil down to a call of `f(int *)` resolves to `f<int *>(int *)` instead of the expected `f(const int *)`.  I found this shocking and completely unintuitive.

Is this a bug in g++, a dark corner of C++, or obvious for some reason I am missing?  If it's not a bug, what's the theory or logic behind it?  Are there any safe practices regarding this issue?

Comment: `f(int)` and `f(const int)` are identical prototypes as far as ANSI c++ compiler is concerned

Comment: Right, but `f(int *)` is not the same as `f(const int *)/f(int const *)`

Comment: Perhaps. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121525/const-pointers-in-overload-resolution/2121616#2121616

Comment: +1 for providing a minimal, complete example program. See http://sscce.org for reasons why that's a good idea.

Comment: @sehe "Perhaps"? I think you are misreading the discussion at that link.  "foo(int *const a)" accepts a const-pointer-to-int. In the example here, "f(const int * a)" accepts a pointer-to-const-int.

Answer (score 8):

For the instantiated template `f<int *>` no conversion (`int *`->`const int *`) is needed, so it's a better match - actually, it's an exact match, that would lose only against a non-templated exact match, which is what happens for the second call.

The full explanation of the "better match" rules is available at §13.3.3 of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4):

Well, why are you calling the const version of the function "expected" in case of `f(&x)` call?

The argument type is `int *`, as you already know. So the `f(int *)` version of the function is a better match than `f(const int *)` version, because in the former the argument type matches *exactly*. The compiler sees the opportunity to generate `f(int *)` from the template and it takes that opportunity. That's just how it works in C++.

In cases when the template version is as good as the non-template one, the non-template one normally wins. But in this case, where the template version is obviously better, the template version wins.

Apparently you expected the compiler to choose the non-template version of the function. Why?

Comment: I expected it to win due to a trivial and implicit const conversion.  It just seems sane to me that const upgrading a pointer type would always occur before considering templates.  Perhaps there's an example as to why that would not be a good idea.

Comment: @Roland : No conversion > trivial conversion in overload resolution.

Comment: @Roland: imagine that you have two ways to perform an operation. It is destructive (with regard to its argument). In the `const` version, you therefore need to perform a copy of the argument first, which is obviously less efficient. Example: `T&& operator+(T&&, T const&)` is more efficient than `T operator+(T const&, T const&)`.

Comment: In that case I agree simply because those are both templates. I simply meant that I expected implicit const conversion before considering any templates at all.