# interaction of pointer and const and overload

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, overloading

As you will see, I am not very confident on my understanding of what happens when mixing pointers const and overload. So following on [questions such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121525/const-pointers-in-overload-resolution), I tried to explicit all cases in the following piece of code.

My question is : did I miss some cases of interactions between addresses, pointers, const pointers, and the various prototypes that may overload each other ?

```
//g++  7.4.0
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ---------- which legal overloads ?
/* 
void f_012a( int* pi ){ cout << "pi"; }
//void f_012a( int * const pi ){ cout << "pci"; } //error: redefinition of ‘void f_012a(int*)’
void f_012a( const int * pi ){ cout << "pci"; }
//void f_012a( const int * const  pi ){ cout << "cpci"; } //error: redefinition of ‘void f_012a(const int*)’
*/

// ---------- overloads declaration order impact ?
void f_01( int* pi )       { cout << "pi";  }
void f_01( const int * pi ){ cout << "pci"; }
void f_10( const int * pi ){ cout << "pci"; }
void f_10( int* pi )       { cout << "pi";  }

int main(){
    cout << "/** trace\n";
    {
        cout << "-------- pointers and const\n";
        int* pi                = new int(1);
        int * const pci        = new int(2);
        const int * cpi        = new int(3);
        const int * const cpci = new int(4);
        cout << "pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 

        *pi  = 5;
        cout << "pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 
        pi   = new int(6);
        cout << "pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 

        *pci  = 7;
        cout << "pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 
        //pci   = new int(8); //error: assignment of read-only variable ‘pci’

        //*cpi  = 8;
        cpi   = new int(8);  //error: assignment of read-only location ‘* cpi’
        cout << "pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 

        //*cpci  = 9;          //error: assignment of read-only location ‘* cpi’
        //cpci   = new int(9); //error: assignment of read-only variable ‘cpci’
    }
    
    {
        cout << "-------- pointers, const, and overload\n";
        int i                  = 1;
        int* pi                = new int(2);
        int * const pci        = new int(3);
        const int * cpi        = new int(4);
        const int * const cpci = new int(5);
        cout << " i : " << i << " / pi -> " << *pi  << " / pci -> " << *pci << " / cpi -> " << *cpi << " / cpci -> " << *cpci << "\n"; 
    
        cout << "var\tf_01\tf_10\n"; 
        cout << "&i\t"; f_01(&i); cout<<"\t"; f_10(&i); cout<<"\n"; 
        cout << "pi\t"; f_01(pi); cout<<"\t"; f_10(pi); cout<<"\n"; 
        cout << "pci\t"; f_01(pci); cout<<"\t"; f_10(pci); cout<<"\n"; 
        cout << "cpi\t"; f_01(cpi); cout<<"\t"; f_10(cpi); cout<<"\n"; 
        cout << "cpci\t"; f_01(cpci); cout<<"\t"; f_10(cpci); cout<<"\n"; 
    }
        
    cout << "*/\n";
    return 0;
}

/** trace
-------- pointers and const
pi -> 1 / pci -> 2 / cpi -> 3 / cpci -> 4
pi -> 5 / pci -> 2 / cpi -> 3 / cpci -> 4
pi -> 6 / pci -> 2 / cpi -> 3 / cpci -> 4
pi -> 6 / pci -> 7 / cpi -> 3 / cpci -> 4
pi -> 6 / pci -> 7 / cpi -> 8 / cpci -> 4
-------- pointers, const, and overload
 i : 1 / pi -> 2 / pci -> 3 / cpi -> 4 / cpci -> 5
var f_01    f_10
&i  pi  pi
pi  pi  pi
pci pi  pi
cpi pci pci
cpci    pci pci
*/
```

Comment: From the caller's view the parameters `int *` and `int * const` are equal, you want to call the function with an `int *`. The second version only gives you the information, that the function does not change the pointer, which you do not care, as it is a copy of your pointer.

Comment: what is explained in the Q&A you link applies in general. Unless `T` is a reference `void foo(const T)` and `void foo(T)` declare the same function. Pointers are not that special as you might think, hence it is not clear what you are looking for as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue at play here is with understading the "right-to-left" rule regarding types.  It is slightly confused by the existence of the "special case of leftmost const" in which `const char` is equivalent to `char const`.

In Nicolai Josuttis' book "C++ Templates" he makes the case of preferring "const right" to avoid using the special case, so the right-to-left rule is made consistent.  Another advocate of this is Dan Saks in this video "East const but constexpr West" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6s6bacI424

There are a number of articles which explain the right-to-left rule and there is a `cdecl` tool which describes C types in plain English.  See [How do you read C declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89056/how-do-you-read-c-declarations) and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations

There is also a web-based cdecl: https://cdecl.org/

Note also there are differences between passing parameters by *value* and by *reference*.  When you pass a pointer to a method by value, you're essentially giving it a copy and it's up to the method to declare whether or not it will mutate the copy.  When you pass a parameter by reference, you are *sharing* the variable, so a const reference cannot be mutated by the method.

---

The compiler's task is to choose the appropriate overload, which the linker connects according to the function's ***mangled name***.  This is how overloads work in the binary context.

Interestingly, in the Visual-C++ compiler, the name mangling *is* different when a pass-by-value parameter is const.  This example looks at the 8 combinations of using a pointer-to-int, pointer-to-int-const, passing by value (const and not), passing by reference (const and not).

Note that if the methods are all called `f_01` the compiler complains because it's presented with multiple possible options and cannot resolve the ambiguity, since you can pass a mutable-value to a const-value method.

```
// These do not affect the value of the pointer in the caller
void f_01(int* pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    // can mutate *pi and can increment the pointer
    *pi = 1;
    pi++;
}

void f_02(int* const pi)
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    // can mutate *pi but cannot increment the pointer
    *pi = 1;
    //pi++;
}

void f_03(int const* pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    // cannot mutate *pi but can increment the pointer
    //*pi = 1;
    pi++;
}

void f_04(int const* const pi)
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    //*pi = 1;
    //pi++;
}

// These could affect the value of the pointer in the caller
void f_05(int*& pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    *pi = 1;
    pi++;       //this will mutate the pointer in the caller
}

void f_06(int const*& pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    // cannot mutate the value addressed by the pointer -> *pi = 1;
    pi++;  //this will mutate the pointer in the caller
}

void f_07(int* const& pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    *pi = 1;
    // cannot do pi++;
}

void f_08(int const* const& pi) 
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", _CRT_WIDE(__FUNCDNAME__));

    // cannot do *pi = 1;
    // cannot do pi++;
}

// --------------------------------

void test_f()
{
    int const constInt = 9;
    int mutableInt = 10;
    int const* pConstInt{ &constInt };
    int* pMutableInt{ &mutableInt };

    f_01(pMutableInt);
    f_02(pMutableInt);
    f_03(pConstInt);
    f_04(pConstInt);

    f_07(pMutableInt);
    f_08(pConstInt);
    // do these last!
    f_05(pMutableInt);
    f_06(pConstInt);

    // output is:
    //? f_01@@YAXPAH@Z
    //? f_02@@YAXQAH@Z
    //? f_03@@YAXPBH@Z
    //? f_04@@YAXQBH@Z

    //? f_07@@YAXABQAH@Z
    //? f_08@@YAXABQBH@Z
    //? f_05@@YAXAAPAH@Z
    //? f_06@@YAXAAPBH@Z
```

---

Taking this a step further, here we demonstrate that you can pass the mutable value to the const methods.  Note the exception with the mutable reference to const pointer - in this case the parameter cannot be converted:

```
    // here we demonstrate that you can pass the mutable int to the const int methods
    // - which is why the overload ambiguity would occur
    f_01(pMutableInt);
    f_02(pMutableInt);
    f_03(pMutableInt);
    f_04(pMutableInt);

    f_07(pMutableInt);
    f_08(pMutableInt);
    f_05(pMutableInt);
    //f_06(pMutableInt); - this is not allowed
```

---

So what's the point of all of this?  Essentially only use overloads when there is no possibility of ambiguity.  Personally I avoid using them.