# Templated functions overload return type

Tags: c++

The following doesn't look like a partial specialization (that however cannot happen on a templated function). Plus functions don't overload by just return type. What's going on in the following code??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
T foo() {
 std::cout << "first";
 return T();   
}


template<typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T,U> foo() {
 std::cout << "second";
 return std::make_pair<T,U>(T(),U()); 
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    foo<int,char>();
}
```

Comment: You have two distinct templates, one with one argument, the other with two (no `foo` overload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two overloads of `foo` (really two function templates named `foo`). One takes one template type argument:

```
template<typename T>
T foo();
```

And one takes two template type arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T,U> foo();
```

You are allowed to overload on different template arguments. You could even add overloads that take non-type arguments:

```
template <int I>
void foo() {
    std::cout << "third";
}
```

This is a separate, valid overload too. What you can't do is then separately add:

```
template <typename U>
U* foo();
```

Because now you have two different function templates named `foo` that take a single template argument and there's no way for the compiler to know which one you meant - so now you have a guaranteed ambiguous overload.

Comment: Uhm, then what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174300/function-template-overloading ? Why are 1 and 3 allowed?

Comment: @Albert 1 takes an `X` and an `int`, 3 takes an `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. There's no ambiguity.

Comment: Uh, and even this falls in the same "non-partial-specialization" stuff? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ac30701c6ec6d0e (last question to clear everything up)

Comment: @Albert Nothing here has anything to do with specialization. In that example, one function takes a template template class with one type argument and the other function takes a template template class with two type arguments. They are not specializations of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I won't call it overload , but compiler will generate two different functions based on template arguments.