# Why is my function overload not preferred over my templated one?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overload-resolution

According to the first answer to this question: [function template overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174300/function-template-overloading), a *"A non-templated (or "less templated") overload is preferred to templates"*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void f1(std::string const& str) {
    std::cout << "f1 " << str << "\n";
}

template <typename Callback, typename... InputArgs>
void call(Callback callback, InputArgs ...args) {
    callback(args...);
}

void call(std::function<void(std::string const&)> callback, const char *str) {
    std::cout << "custom call: ";
    callback(str);
}

int main() {
    auto f2 = [](std::string const& str) -> void {
        std::cout << "f2 " << str << "\n";
    };

    call(f1, "Hello World!");
    call(f2, "Salut Monde !");

    return 0;
}
```

Where, as far as I understand it, the second definition of `call` is "non-templated", and thus should be chosen over the first one when I do `call(f1, "1")` or `call(f2, "2")`.

This is not the case, I get the following output:

```
f1 Hello World!
f2 Salut Monde !
```

If I remove the templated version of `call`, I get the expected output.

**Why is my overload of `call` not chosen over the first one in this case?**

Comment: The non-template is only preferred when the parameter type is an exact match. In the thread you linked to, note the example where `10` matches the non-template but `10u` matches the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types for `f1` and `f2` are not `std::function`, a user defined conversion is needed, thus the template version is chosen instead.

If you did provide a function `call` that is an exact match for a function pointer, such as;

```
void call (void(*callback)(std::string const&), const char *str)
```

It would be chosen for `f1`.

---

*Note*: with the addition of the unary `+` on the lambda, you can also get a function pointer in this case (your capture list is empty)...

```
auto f2 = +[](std::string const& str) -> void
//        ^ unary +
```

Comment: One of the classic articles on overloaded and specialised template functions is this from Herb Sutter; http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 3):

The type of the lambda `f2` is not `std::function<void(std::string const&)>`, it [is a compiler generated type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11). Therefore the templated `call` provided a better match.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `f1` or `f2`are of type `std::function<...>`. Therefore the template is a better match.

If you use (as example)

```
std::function<void(std::string const&)> f3(f2);
call(f3, "Salut Monde !");
```

your call is used.

Answer (score 1):

[std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) could be constructed from function or lambda expressions, but its type is *not* same as function or lambda expressions. The arguments don't match perfectly for:

```
call(f1, "Hello World!");
call(f2, "Salut Monde !");
```

You can use casting to accomplish it:

```
call(static_cast<std::function<void(std::string const&)>>(f1), "Hello World!");
call(static_cast<std::function<void(std::string const&)>>(f2), "Salut Monde !");
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/WOCXD56722)

Answer (score -1):

when you overload the function with specific type(function's second argument) in this case when you call the function with specific argument then template function will not call because you already write the function for specific type. except the specific type your template function call , it is compiler jobs to select specific type argument first and then template function