# Pass a variable number of parameters to an embedded python API

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Today I was reading about embedded python in C++ at

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

So, I can call a python code in C++.

But the way python is called in the API example does not look cool to me.

I was thinking about calling a python function from C++ in any arbitrary  way like:

```
py_call(script_path,module_name,str1,int2,long3,float4,str5,double6);
```

or

```
py_call(script_path,module_name,x,y,z,title);
```

But I need to use a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). This is the first time I see parameter pack. I have stuck right here and I do not know how to replace `argc` and `argv` parameters in the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void py_call(
        const string &script,
        const string &module,
        T value, Targs... Fargs
    )
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(script.c_str());
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, module.c_str());
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyLong_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", module.c_str());
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n",script.c_str());
        return 1;
    }
}
```

PS. `argc=sizeof...(Fargs)+1` or `argc=sizeof...(Fargs)` depending on the function implementation.

Comment: Your `py_call` uses a mixture of types, whereas in your example, all arguments are converted to `int`. The `argv` from where you have taken some parts, are all `char*`. If you want a single solution to cover all signatures, you need to convert all types to PyObjects - not just integers. I can recommend you to look into SWIG

Comment: @JensMunk Is it possible that I write a user defined type-case?

Comment: Even better, you could use template function overloads, such that if the type is integer, `PyLong_FromLong` is used and another function if the type is double. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174300/function-template-overloading

Comment: The author of FluentCPP explains it quite well, https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/15/function-templates-partial-specialization-cpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice splitting construction of `argv` tuple from the rest of your code. In order to construct this tuple, you need to iterate over the parameter pack and for each parameter create a `PyObject` by means of overloading. C++11 version could look somehow like this:

```
void to_py_tuple_impl(PyObject*, size_t) {}

template<typename ParamType, typename... ParamTypesTail>
void to_py_tuple_impl(PyObject* tpl, size_t index, const ParamType& param, const ParamTypesTail&... tail)
{
    // error checking omitted for clarity
    PyTuple_SetItem(tpl, index, to_py_object(param));
    to_py_tuple_impl(tpl, index + 1, tail...);
}

template<typename... ParamTypes>
PyObject* to_py_tuple(const ParamTypes&... args)
{
    PyObject* tpl = PyTuple_New(sizeof...(ParamTypes));
    to_py_tuple_impl(tpl, 0, args...);
    return tpl;
}
```

If you have to stick with C++11, you need to use a recursive function to iterate over `args` - that's what `to_py_tuple_impl` does. I've wrapped it into `to_py_tuple` for simplicity.

This code calls `to_py_object` for each argument in order to convert it to `PyObject*` and inserts that object into a tuple.

`to_py_object` can be overloaded to support multiple types, for example:

```
PyObject* to_py_object(const std::string& str)
{
    return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(str.c_str(), str.size());
}

PyObject* to_py_object(const char* str)
{
    retrurn PyUnicode_FromString(str);
}
```

Number of overloads can be reduced using templates and `std::enable_if`:

```
// Converts all integer types:
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, PyObject*> to_py_object(T value)
{
    return PyLong_FromLong(value);
}

// Converts all floating point types:
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, PyObject*> to_py_object(T value)
{
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(value);
}
```

Now, you can just plug it into your `py_call` function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void py_call(
        const string &script,
        const string &module,
        T value, Targs... Fargs
    )
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(script.c_str());
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, module.c_str());
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = to_py_tuple(Fargs...);
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

            ...
```