# what is the difference between function declaration and signature?

Tags: c++, c, function, declaration, signature

In C or C++ what is the difference between function declaration and function signature?

I know something of function declaration but function signature is totally new to me. What is the point of having the concept of function signature? What are the two concepts used for actually?

Thanks!

Comment: Formally, there's no such thing as "function signature" in C. In C there's simply no need for the concept of "function signature". Your question is purely C++. It is totally meaningless in C.

Comment: Then surely a meaningful answer in C is "none", no?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A function declaration is the prototype for a function (or it can come from the function definition if no prototype has been seen by the compiler at that point) - it includes the return type, the name of the function and the types of the parameters (optionally in C).

A function signature is the parts of the function declaration that the compiler uses to perform overload resolution. Since multiple functions might have the same name (ie., they're overloaded), the compiler needs a way to determine which of several possible functions with a particular name a function call should resolve to.  The signature is what the compiler considers in that overload resolution. Specifically, the standard defines 'signature' as:

> the information about a function that participates in overload resolution: the types of its parameters and, if the function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function itself and the class in which the member function is declared.

Note that the return type is not part of the function signature. As the standard says in a footnote, "Function signatures do not include return type, because that does not participate in overload resolution".

Comment: It is not exactly correct to say that "function declaration is the prototype". In C++ it is practically correct, but terminologically wrong, since in C++ there's no such term as "prototype". In C it is strictly incorrect because in C function declaration is not necessarily a prototype. For example, `void foo();` is a function declaration that does not introduce a prototype in C. Actually, this question is not supposed to be tagged C, since there's no notion of "function signature" in C. It is purely a C++ question and, for this reason, the answer should not mention any "prototypes".

Comment: Could you please cite sources?

Comment: You introduced "signature," "declaration," "prototype," and "definition" without clear distinctions. Could you edit this to add a concrete example of each?

Answer (score 7):

The standard defines two terms: declaration and definition. A definition is a tentative declaration. However, the C99 and C++03 standards have slightly varying definitions.

From C++0x draft:

> **Appendix C**
>
> **8.3.5** Change: In C++, a function declared
> with an empty parameter list takes no
> arguments. In C, an empty parameter
> list means that the number and type of
> the function arguments are unknown"
>
> **Definitions**
>
> **1.3.11  signature**
>
> the name and the parameter-type-list
> (8.3.5) of a function, as well as the
> class, concept, concept map, or
> namespace of which it is a member. If
> a function or function template is a
> class member its signature
> additionally includes the
> cv-qualifiers (if any) and the
> ref-qualifier (if any) on the function
> or function template itself. The
> signature of a constrained member
> (9.2) includes its template
> requirements. The signature of a
> function template additionally
> includes its return type, its template
> parameter list, and its template
> requirements (if any). The signature
> of a function template specialization
> includes the signature of the template
> of which it is a specialization and
> its template arguments (whether
> explicitly specified or deduced). [
> Note: Signatures are used as a basis
> for name mangling and linking.—end
> note ]

Comment: Thanks but I feel difficult to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I know of function declaration but function signature is totally new to me. What is the point of having the concept of function signature? What are the two concepts used for actually?

Comment: @Tim: 1) The C standard does not define the term signature. It is used in general programming literature loosely and is often synonymous with a function declaration. Note that function declarations need not have parameters. Definitions do, though, if you are using them in the definition. 2) Signatures are widely used by the compiler to e.g. provide a definition for an identifier and in case of C++ choose the best overload.

Answer (score 5):

The function signature doesn't include the return type or linkage type of the function.

OK, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(computer_science)) disagrees with me on the return type being included. However I know that the return type is not used by the compiler when deciding if a function call matches the signature.  This previous StackOverflow question appears to agree: [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature)

Comment: Does "storage class" mean the class which the function belongs to? What is the point of having the concept of function signature? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim: No. They refer to the linkage applicable.

Comment: I wouldn't put too much credence in Wikipedia's article right now. It's not well written. The *Method signature* article is a little better.

Comment: I suspect I'm confusing my terminology - storage class refers to variables, not functions. What I meant is the characteristics implied by the static or extern keywords for example. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: `static` and `extern` are storage classes that *can* apply to functions in both C and C++.

Comment: In C++ the return type is not part of the function signature, regardless of what Wikipedia says, though return type might be part of the function signature for other languages (I honestly don't know).

Answer (score 3):

Also please note that top-level const and volatile on argument are not part of the signature, according to the standard.  But some compilers get this wrong.

e.g.

```
void f(const int, const char* const);
```

has the same signature as

```
void f(int, const char*);
```

Answer (score -1):

A function declaration is a prototype. A function signature indicates what is the return type and the parameters used that makes up the signature. Consider this:

```
int foo(int, int);  /* Function Declaration */


/* Implementation of foo 
** Function signature
*/
int foo(int a, int b){
}
```

Now, consider this scenario: a programmer is asked what is the function signature for `foo`:

- It returns a datatype of `int`
- Two parameters are also of datatype of `int`, named `a` and `b` respectively

The function prototype on the other hand is to clue in the C/C++ compiler, on what to expect and if the signature does not match up with the prototype, the compiler will emit an error, along the context of 'function declaration error' or 'prototype mismatch'.

Comment: Thanks! So the function signature is the part of the function definition that corresponds to the function declaration?

Comment: @Tim: Yes. Exactly. :) Hope that makes sense to you?

Comment: In C, a function declaration may not be a prototype: `int f();` is an example.