# Are the function specifiers and the storage class specifiers part of the type of a function?

Tags: c

When we define a function in C,

```
extern/static inline/_Noreturn myfunction(){};
```

are the function specifiers  (e.g. `inline`  or `_Noreturn`) , and  the storage class specifiers  (e.g. `extern`  or  `static`)  part of the type of the function?

Comment: no, the signature is only based on the name.

Comment: functions are extern by default. If I do understand you well - the type is not

Comment: No.  You do nothing different depending on whether the function is inline or not, or if it is static or not; there is nothing about the type of the return value (or argument list) in that information.  The `_Noreturn` case is slightly different, but it still isn't a part of the type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between function declaration and signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322736/what-is-the-difference-between-function-declaration-and-signature)