# In Objective-C why is id used as return type for init methods?

Tags: objective-c

I did some quick searching and couldn't find an answer for this.

I'm interested to know why in Objective-C, `id` is used as the return type for init methods.

My guess is that it's because if the class is overridden, you don't want to return an object of the superclass's type, but I'm interested to know if it's done for some other reason.

Comment: Dear person that downvoted this question about 7 hours ago, if you're going to downvote a question that, based on the number of upvotes and favorites, has obviously helped multiple peoples' understanding of Objective-C, including my own, at least add a comment as to why...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yup. Your idea is right on the money. A subclass should still be able to use its superclass's initialization methods and return its own type instead of the super type and returning `id` allows it to do that.

Comment: Related reading: Clang has introduced a new keyword, `instancetype` which makes type checking possible while preserving this feature of inheritance on methods other than `init`. See [Would it be beneficial to begin using instancetype instead of id?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8972221)

Answer (score 5):

The superclass type idea, while a good theory, doesn't really stand up: A `NSString *` ***is*** a `NSObject *`. There's no reason it can't be referred to as such.

Instead, I think it has more to do with function signatures. In a dynamic language like Objective-C, you can have no idea what class you're messaging. But the compiler **must** know what type is being returned. That and Objective-C's history of convention-based programming (rather than having strict rules) means that your subclass *could* return a `NSRect` (a `struct`) or `NSInteger` (a scalar) from `init`. It was kooky, but valid.

C++ has a similar problem, see [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature).

So we needed a single type for all methods with a signature of `-(id)init`, and `id` was the only thing that made sense as it specified only that the return type was an instance. That's enough for the compiler to do the right thing. Now we have `instancetype`, which matches the class being messaged.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the necromancy here; I came here as a result of the Related sidebar. :)

Comment: No worries, extra insight is always welcome. I posted this question out of curiosity more than anything.

Comment: No there is a possibility that you want a subclass returned, but don't write your own init method (you are hijacking the init from the parent class). I want a 'special' [[NSSuperString alloc] init] WITHOUT casting. When returning NSString in the init, I would need to (NSSuperString *)[[NSSuperString alloc] init] so the static analyzer would see that I have a subclass (of course when NSSuperString has no implementation of init). When declaring to a local var, there would be a warning without casting too.

Comment: If you use `[NSSuperString alloc] init]`, with or without `NSSuperString` having an `init`, `instancetype` means you get a `NSSuperString` back. That's part of `instancetype`.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime Apple added a new way to declare the return type of `init` methods.

It is `instancetype`. Read more about it e.g. [here](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/)

Comment: As I understand it, Clang actually automatically treats id as instancetype internally for init methods (I don't think it does for class convenience methods though)

Answer (score 2):

it's possible for init to actually return an instance of a different class, so `id` is used. can't say i've ever seen this happen in practice, but hey :)

Comment: You're using it in practice all the time: `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, `NSString`/`NSMutableString`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Then why not making it return a NSArray* instead of id? Polymorphism is still valid.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Semantic issue: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: That's just duck typing. It doesn't matter what the type actually is; what matters is that it can be treated like the type you asked for. If you asked for an `NSMutableArray` to be constructed, you can treat the result as if it was an `NSMutableArray`. Even if it isn't.