# Type of Function in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, typechecking

I have a simple question:

> What is the type of function in C or C++

As we can have pointers to function in C or C++, that means functions should have a specific type otherwise type checking during pointers to function creation have no meaning.

Can someone explain me, I am on the correct path or not?

If I am on the right path, How can I find the type of function?

Comment: Do you know how to declare a pointer-to-function variable? If so, you know the answer to your question already.

Comment: `typeid(function).name()` will usually return a user readable type for you.

Comment: C/C++ don't have first class functions so they don't really have an actual type.

Comment: they are void function pointers. they are a special void type :)

Comment: @Pubby: Of course functions have types. One might say they're not "first class" types since you can't declare a variable of that type; but they certainly are actual types.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as @Shark. If we look at function as a type, it's just a void pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Syntax for function pointers

The type of a function in C/C++ includes both the `return type` and the `types of input parameters` .

Consider the following function declaration:

```
int function(char, float);
```

A pointer to that function has the following type:

```
int (*funptr)(char, float);
```

Similarly in general :

```
returntype function (argtype1, argtype2, argtype3)
```

A corresponding pointer to such a function is

```
returntype (*ptr) (atgtype1, atgtype2, atgtype3);
```

There are be many different types of functions. Find a [**useful reference on function pointers here**](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx10.html).

Also, this classification is based on the `return type and argument types`. Functions *can also be classified on the basis of scope of their accessibility.* like global functions, static functions etc. See here [for a short introduction](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/239347-static-functions-and-variables-in-c/).

Answer (score 7):

Of course every function has it types,

for example, function

```
double foo(bar& f, const const baz*)
```

has a type of

```
function, that accepts reference to bar and constant pointer to baz and return double
```

It can be written like

```
double ()(bar&, const baz*)
```

A pointer to variable of types of that function will have type (variable that can store pointer to that function)

will have type

```
double (*)(bar&, const baz*)
```

Or, if you want to `typedef` a pointer to functions of that type you can write

```
typedef double (*func_ptr)(bar&, const baz*)
```

Again,

```
func_ptr is a type of pointer to function, that accepts reference to bar and constant pointer to baz and return double
```

One thing here is that function decays to pointer to function, so you can write

```
func_ptr f = &foo;
```

and

```
func_ptr g = foo;
```

And it would be the same.

---

Now imagine, that you have

```
struct A
{
    double goo(bar& f, const const baz*);
};
```

Now `goo` has a type of

```
function of struct A, that accepts reference to bar and constant pointer to baz and return double
```

A pointer to this function will have type

```
double (A::*)(bar&, const baz*)
```

Note, that it types *differs* from type of free function `foo`. They are not compatible at all.

However, if `goo` were `static` function, the fact that it belongs to `struct A` would be insufficient (as far as member function requires implicit `this` argument and `static` function does not).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `function signature` which should match either with `declaration` or with `function pointer`

Function signature contains everything as such arguments type , no of arguments and return type.

Directly like variables you cannot say that particular function is of `int` type or `float` or `char` type or so on

Always remember it's `signature` as i said above.

Comment: Function's signature do not contain return type always, You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature

Comment: Yeah, but only on the basis of return type you cannot do function overloading .. or distinguish a function . because returned value may be ignored by our requirement.. sometimes it's not needed

Comment: A function has a type, just like everything else.  The type is based on its signature, but it is part of the type system.  (Unlike the signature, the type also includes the return type.)

Comment: @neel : Yeah but if we don't mention return type then it will be problem in creating a function pointer.

Comment: @Omkant thats what I am saying function signature is not same as function type.

Comment: neel : read my third line of my answer also the comments which James Kanze has written "the type is based on it's signature"..

Answer (score -2):

Every pair of two types (A,B) has a specific function type A->B. If we choose A=int, B=float, then the function type would become:

```
float my_function(int a);
```

Comment: if we have to give more no of arguments and of different types how will you show this relationship

Comment: this isn't even close to a sensible explanation, much less an acceptable answer.