# From Josuttis: Do different template functions, that instantiate to the same function signature given particular types, result in ODR invalidity?

Tags: c++, templates

In Josuttis' and Vandevoorde's well-known book on templates, [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://amzn.com/0201734842), they discuss details regarding the overloading of function templates.

In one of their examples, related to a discussion of function signatures and overloaded function templates, they present code that they describe in the following terms:

```
This program is valid and produces the following output:

(Note: Output shown below)
```

However, when I build and compile the identical code in Visual Studio 2010, I get a different result.  This leads me to believe that either the VS 2010 compiler is producing incorrect code, or that Josuttis is incorrect that the code is valid.

Here is the code.  (Josuttis 2003, Section 12.2.1)

```
// File1.cpp

#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f1(T2, T1)
{
    std::cout << "f1(T2, T1)" << std::endl;
}

extern void g();

int main()
{
    f1<char, char>('a', 'b');
    g();
}
```

...

```
// File2.cpp

#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void f1(T1, T2)
{
    std::cout << "f1(T1, T2)" << std::endl;
}

void g()
{
    f1<char, char>('a', 'b');
}
```

(Notice the reversal of type arguments in the two template function definitions.  Note also that this reversal has no effect when the two type arguments are the same, as they are for the two functions `f1()` in this code example.)

According to Josuttis:

```
This program is valid and produces the following output:

f1(T2, T1)
f1(T1, T2)
```

When I build and run the identical code, unchanged, in the Visual Studio 2010 compiler, here is my result:

```
f1(T1, T2)
f1(T1, T2)
```

Further, I was wondering how it is possible for the compiler/linker to distinguish between the function `f1` as instantiated in file1.cpp, and the function `f1` as instantiated in file2.cpp, given that (I think) the compiler strips away all "knowledge" of the fact that these functions were created from templates, and has only the information (I think) of the function signature itself: `void (char, char)`, which is the same for both `f1` functions.

Since (if I'm correct) the function signature is identical in the two translation units, I would think that this is an example of a violation of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule) (ODR), and that it would therefore be invalid C++.

However, as I've just noted, Josuttis and Vandevoorde claim that this is *valid* C++.

But since my compiled version of the same code gives *different* results than Josuttis claims is the output, this seems to be an indication that either VS 2010 is producing incorrect code, or Josuttis is incorrect in this case (i.e., the code is invalid and violates the ODR).

Are Josuttis and Vandevoorde incorrect, or is VS 2010 producing incorrect output?  Or is there some other explanation that explains the discrepancy between the output VS 2010 produces, and the output Josuttis reports?

It might be of interest to show the VS 2010 disassembly at the point that each `f1()` is called.

The first call of `f1()` (directly within `main()`):

[image: f1() called directly from within main()]

The second call of `f1()` (from within `g()`):

[image: f1() called from within g()]

Note that the address of `f1()` chosen by the compiler in both cases is the same - 13E11EAh.  To me, this indicates that in fact, the compiler cannot distinguish between the two instantiated function signatures, and this is a case where the ODR is being violated, so the code is *invalid C++* and Josuttis has an error in his book.  But it's just that - an indication.  I don't know.

(I have checked the errata on the book's website, and there is no mention of this example.)

**ADDENDUM** Per a request from a comment, I am attaching relevant output from the .map file for this program that shows the mangled name/s being used for `f1`:

[image: .map file output showing mangled names for <code>f1</code>]

**ADDENDUM 2** Now that the question is answered - Josuttis' book is correct - I want to note that in the Josuttis text, in the same section (12.2.1), it is explicitly outlined exactly what determines a unique function signature, *including the template aspect*.

From the text (among the other, expected things that define a function signature), the TRANSLATION UNIT is part of the function signature; for template functions (only) the RETURN TYPE is part of the function signature, and

> .6. The template parameters and the template arguments, if the function is generated from a function template.

Therefore - it is clear.  Template information must be maintained and tracked by the compiler even after a function template has been instantiated, in order for the compiler/linker to obey the necessary, special rules for templates (as in the case of the code example in my question).

Comment: It would be very useful to also add the actual mangled name for the functions in question.

Comment: @Pedro How can I obtain that?  I'll look now to see how to get it...

Comment: Think about it this way: If you included all the templates in one single file, then the code wouldn't be correct (since the specialisation would be ambiguous). So the code shouldn't be getting any more correct just by splitting it up over different files.

Comment: No answer, but I tried with g++ 4.1.2 and 4.7.2 with and without `--std=c++11`. In all cases the output was as the book describes.

Comment: @Pedro: I have addended the question to include a screenshot of the mangled names (as shown in the .map file).  I can't immediately decipher it.

Comment: Note also that it is the *specialization* (i.e. `f1<char, char>`) that enters the overload set, not the template itself. In your case, you have *two* identical functions in the overload set, but they have different definitions.

Comment: @Kerreck - Agreed.  Hence - if this reasoning is correct - then I'm safe to say that Josuttis' book has an error.

Comment: There is no overload resolution occurring here. In both files, there is only one `f1` known to instantiate. I imagined at first the mangled name for both instatiations would be the same therefore linking was selecting one and discarding other. But this doesn't seem to be exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Pedro The .map file might be produced AFTER the linker selects one and discards the other - so your reasoning might be right.

Comment: You could invite Vandevoorde or Josuttis to this question. If you don't, I will.

Comment: Please do, thanks.  I don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apologies for the earlier, incorrect answer. The example does indeed seem to be correct, and there is actually a similar example in the standard itself (C++11, 14.5.6.1/1-2). Let me just quote it in its entirety:

> 1. It is possible to overload function templates so that two different function template specializations have the same type. [ *Example:*
>
>    ```
>    // file1.c
>
>    template<class T> void f(T*);
>
>    void g(int* p) {
>        f(p); // calls f<int>(int*)
>    }
>
>
>    // file2.c
>
>    template<class T> void f(T);
>
>    void h(int* p) {
>        f(p); // calls f<int*>(int*)
>    }
>    ```
>
>    — *end example* ]
> 2. Such specializations are distinct functions and do not violate the one definition rule (3.2).

In your case, you have two different function templates, both called `f1` (which is fine because you can overload function templates), and they happen to have specializations which have the same type.

Comment: @Xeo: Contrary to my expectations, I couldn't actually find any rule that forbids having different overload sets for a given signature in different TUs. Is there such a rule? The point is that the OP has two distinct functions `file1::f1<char, char>` and `file2::f1<char, char>`, which happen to have the same type (namely `void(char, char)`) but are simply different functions.

Comment: I take back what I said. :) The function template definitions are, in fact, different and can be put in the same TU. The only problem you'll get is that you have an ambiguity when trying to call `f1`. So, this appears to be a VC++ bug. I'll double check, though.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Following up, if the code (in my question) is valid C++, doesn't that imply that the compiler MUST include information in some way involving the original template definition into the compiled code, in order for the linker to disambiguate what otherwise would be a ODR violation?  But I thought that the template origin of functions is compiled away?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: The origin can most definitely be compiled away until after the linking. You will routinely include templates in headers which cause multiple instantiations (think of all those `std::vector<int>`s!), and those are only deduplicated at the linker stage.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems to be a Visual Studio 2010 lack of compatibility with the standard, then.

Comment: Does information regarding the template origin itself need to be included by the compiler - OR, instead, is it simply the fact that template functions are typically defined implicitly `inline` - which (I've learned) requires the standard to allow multiple definitions across TU's - that causes the code to be legal?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: `inline` function templates are different yet again; that's a separate issue (indeed, all definitions of `inline` functions and function templates must be identical). But even instances of ordinary, non-inline function templates with external linkage  must be deduplicated by the linker.

Comment: In addition, template instantiations (rather than explicit sprcializations) are not part of a TU. They are part of IUs, which are instantiation units.