# Using void in header file

Tags: c++

This is my header file, auto vs static.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void IncrementAndPrint()
{
    using namespace std;
    int nValue = 1; // automatic duration by default
    ++nValue;
    cout << nValue << endl;
} // nValue is destroyed here

void print_auto()
{
    IncrementAndPrint();
    IncrementAndPrint();
    IncrementAndPrint();
}

void IncrementAndPrint()
{
    using namespace std;
    static int s_nValue = 1; // fixed duration
    ++s_nValue;
    cout << s_nValue << endl;
} // s_nValue is not destroyed here, but becomes inaccessible

void print_static()
{
    IncrementAndPrint();
    IncrementAndPrint();
    IncrementAndPrint();
}
```

And this is my main file, namearray.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "auto vs static.h"
using namespace std;

    int main(); // changing this to "int main()" (get rid of ;) solves error 5. 
    {
    print_static();
    print_auto();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
    }
```

I'm trying to print (cout)
2
2
2
2
3
4

Errors:

[image: Errors]

I feel that my mistake is just using void in the header file. How can I change the header file so that my code will work?

Reference: code from [learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/41-blocks-compound-statements-and-local-variables/)

Comment: You have the same prototype declared twice for `IncrementAndPrint()`, the fact that the body of the function changes does not matter. The error says it: function "already has a body".

Comment: I don't know exactly, but maybe this is because you have forgotten to declare a function prototype for `IncrementAndPrint()` before defining it. Ie, you have no `void IncrementAndPrint();` prior to declaring the function body. That is just a guess, though, I don't use your compiler chain but GCC.

Comment: To get rid of error 5) I just had to get rid of ; after int main()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike variables, you cannot give a new value to a function. So here is what the compiler thinks:

"Oh, OK, when you say `IncrementAndPrint`, what you mean is this function here at the top of the file".

Then it sees `print_auto` and learns what that means. But then you try to tell it that `IncrementAndPrint` actually means this other function, and the compiler gets confused. "But you already told me what `IncrementAndPrint` means!", complains the compiler.

This contrasts with variables (in some way), where you can say:

```
int x = 0;
x = 6;
```

The compiler understands that at one point, `x` has the value `0`, but then you say "`x` is different now, it means `6`.". However, you cannot say:

```
int x = 0;
int x = 6;
```

Because when you include a type before a variable name, you are defining a new variable. If you do not include a type, you are just assigning to an old one.

You will have to give `IncrementAndPrint` a different name.

Alternatively, you could have them take different arguments, for instance, `void IncrementAndPrint(int x);` vs. `void IncrementAndPrint(double y);`. I don't recommend that here because you don't need the argument.

Another possibility is to use a [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/). It would look something like this:

```
namespace automatic_variables {

void IncrementAndPrint() {
    // automatic variable version
}
void print() {
    // automatic version
}
}
namespace static_variables {

void IncrementAndPrint() {
    // static variable version
}
void print() {
    // static version
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot declare two functions with the same name and parameters.

```
 void IncrementAndPrint()
```

Comment: ... unless they have different parameters

Comment: With the same name *and the same parameters*.

Comment: signature is indeed better

Comment: Well, the signature includes the return type, which is not relevant for overloading.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but I think it's only marginally helpful for a new person. The asker most likely doesn't know what a "signature" means, and may not even think that they are declaring two functions. It looks to me like they were trying to redefine `IncrementAndPrint` later on.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The return type is not part of the signature ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature)).