# "Overloading" constructors with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, constructor-overloading

Why does the the following [attempt](http://cpp.sh/6xnr) at overloading the constructor `Foo::Foo` fail? Also, I'd appreciate alternatives/workarounds

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

namespace xyz
{   
    struct MemoryManager{};

    template<typename T , typename Alloc=MemoryManager>
    class vector
    {
    };
}


template<typename T, template<typename,typename> class V , typename A>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename U = T ,
             typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<
                 std::is_same<std::vector<U>, V<U,A> >::value >::type >
    Foo() // when instantiated with the std vector
    {
    }

    template<typename U = T ,
             typename Dummy = typename std::enable_if<
                 std::is_same<xyz::vector<U>, V<U,A> >::value >::type >
    Foo() // when instantiated with my custom vector
    {
    }   
};

int main()
{
}
```

Error message:

```
23:3: error: ‘template<class T, template<class, class> class V, class A> template<class U, class Dummy> Foo<T, V, A>::Foo()’ cannot be overloaded
   Foo() // when instantiated with my custom vector

18:3: error: with ‘template<class T, template<class, class> class V, class A> template<class U, class Dummy> Foo<T, V, A>::Foo()’
   Foo() // when instantiated with the std vector
```

Comment: Please define "fail", does it not compile? Does it pick the wrong one? Does it crash?

Comment: Don't know if this solves the problem completely, but for `xyz::vector`, you need two template parameters, `xyz::vector<U,A>` instead of just `xyz::vector<U>`.

Comment: @Alejandro No it doesn't, especially as `xyz::vector` has a default argument for itsecond template argument.

Comment: Default arguments are not part of the function signature. You need to do `enable_if_t<...>* = nullptr` in both declarations.

Comment: @Olumide You should add that to your question.

Comment: @Olumide, now it has a default !

Comment: @Barry Added, thanks. It was in the online version.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the suggestion. I got something close to it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't overload the constructors that way because default arguments are not part of the signature. Effectively, you have:

```
template <typename, typename>
Foo();

template <typename, typename>
Foo();
```

This rule may be clearer outside of the template world, where these two functions cannot overload each other:

```
void foo(int x = 42);
void foo(int y = 17);
```

You could instead make the 2nd template argument a defaulted *non-type* parameter, so that the two constructors have different signatures:

```
template<typename U = T , 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::vector<U> , V<T,A> >::value, int> = 0>
Foo() // when instantiated with the std vector
```

Or you could delegate both constructors using a dummy type:

```
template <typename T> struct tag { };

Foo()
: Foo(tag<V<T,A>>{})
{ }

Foo(tag<std::vector<T>> )
{ /* std vector */ }

Foo(tag<xyz::vector<T>> )
{ /* your vector */ }
```

Comment: Return types are not part of the function signature either, so why does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd0cebf2632013a9) work?

Comment: @templateboy That's an entirely different question. You should start a new thread.

Comment: @templateboy: not true for template specializations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/290048/27678

Comment: Note that you are effectively using `void *` as a template non-type parameter, which is technically ill-formed (but works on all three major compilers anyway).