# What does std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (ClassName::*)()>(ClassName*)> mean? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make sense of what this means in my compiler debug output:

```
std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (ClassName::*)()>(ClassName*)>
```

If it matters, it's being used as the value for a template variable that's being used as the type for a class member variable.

The bit I *know* I'm not sure of is `"ClassName::*"` (Google is *really* *bad* when the important bit of what you're searching for is the non-alphanumeric bit)

Comment: I'm guessing a captured member function with `this` pointer as argument, something compiler-formed of `std::bind(&class::obj,&myobj);`

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that `_Bind` is that implementation's type returned by `std::bind` and likewise for `_Mem_fn`. I would guess at this being Microsoft's.

Comment: That makes some sense, as I am using std::bind like that, but all the functions I'm binding have an int return, so where would the void come from?

Comment: If this is Microsoft's then I'm a dead penguin. This is GCC output, and I'm running on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With reference to the bit you *know* you're not sure about, `ClassName::*`:

`ClassName::*` is part of a type (but only *part*) - the complete type is `void (ClassName::*)()`, which is the syntax for a [**member function pointer**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types)

Specifically here, you have a pointer to a `ClassName` member function, which returns `void` and takes no parameters.

```
    void (ClassName::*)()
      ^          ^      ^
      |          |      | 
return type      |      |
(void)           |      |
                 |      |
class type ------+      |
(ClassName)             | 
                        | 
parameter list ---------+
(no parameters)
```

As for the rest of the type, `std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (ClassName::*)()>(ClassName*)>`, this is the internal representation of calling [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

The signature of `std::bind` is as follows:

```
template< class F, class... Args >
/*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Note the *unspecified* return type - this means it is up to the implementation to decide what `std::bind` returns:

> **Return value**
>   A function object of unspecified type T, for which `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true`

So in this particular implementation, `std::bind` for the `ClassName` member function you've passed returns `std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (ClassName::*)()>(ClassName*)>`

**How is this useful?**

One thing you can do with the return type of `std::bind` is capture it in a `std::function`

The *particular* `std::function` type in question here would be `std::function<void()>`.

```
ClassName obj;
std::function<void()> func = std::bind(&ClassName::someFunction, &obj);

func(); // this actually calls obj.someFunction()
```

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense, except that the only member functions I use bind on have a return type of int.  In more detail, all the functions that use bind use this prototype: 'std::function<int(int x, int y, bool& handled, bool& close)>' (Yes, I'm using std::placeholders::_1... in what I pass to Bind())

Comment: Well the return type of a function doesn't form part of its signature (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature))

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the correct version of `_Bind`? The member function pointer being passed to `bind` that you're posting (`void (ClassName::*)()`) doesn't match the one in your comment, which would be `int (ClassName::*)(int, int, bool&)`

Comment: Turns out you're right, I had a few other calls to bind that I'd forgotten about completely.