# Why is the `int* Get()` called insted of `const int& Get()`?

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution

I have a class `B` that has two methods, where one returns a pointer to a member variable and the other returns a const reference to the variable.

I try to call those methods. During the calls, I store the return values to respective return types.

I was expecting the appropriate return types would end up calling the appropriate methods, but I get a compilation error saying:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   const int& refval2 =  b.Get(); `
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
class B{
public:
  int* Get(){
    return &x_;
  }
  const int & Get() const{
    return x_;
  }

private:
  int x_ = 0;
};

int main(){
  B b;
  const int& refval2 =  b.Get(); 
  int* pval2 =  b.Get(); 
}
```

Comment: Return types are not used when selecting an overloaded function to be called.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure proper function is called?

Comment: By the rules of C++ the "proper" function is called, but the return type is wrong.

Comment: [Sure. Easy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/445c96a2e05c881b)

Comment: I'd rename one to `GetPtr()`, and leave the other one as `Get`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Now that is clever.  Something I wouldn't have thought of.  I'll add that to me toolbox.

Comment: Try std::as_const

Comment: Doing `const int& refval2 = static_cast<const B>(b).Get();` also works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Return type is not part of function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/290038/3309790), it's not considered in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

> In general, the candidate function whose parameters match the arguments most closely is the one that is called.

For non-static member function call, the type of the object to be called on involves too. There're two `Get()`, one is const and one is non-const. For `b.Get();`, the non-const `Get()` is an exact match; for the const `Get()` to be called the object `b` has to be converted to `const`. Then the non-const one wins, after that the compiler will try to convert the returned `int*` to `const int&` and fails.

So

```
B b;
int* pval2 =  b.Get();          // call to non-const Get()

const B cb;
const int& refval2 =  cb.Get(); // call to const Get()
```

Comment: if I may ask what's the rule why `int* Get()` was chosen when the receiving end is a `const int&`?

Comment: @codekaizer: `b` is non-const, so the non-const `Get` is always called. `cb` is const, so the const `Get` is always called. It depends on the type of the class with the member, not the return value.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I agree. makes sense. if I may ask one last question. I don't see it in the standard's *over.load* or *over.match.best* section. is this specified in another section where matching is based on the object `const`-ness?

Comment: ok now everything makes sense. Thank you @MooingDuck for that code snippet though.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the `int* Get()` called insted of `const int& Get()`?

```
const int & Get() const
```

Is a `const` member function.

From [class.this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#class.this-1):

> If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`

However, you declared:

```
B b;
```

as non-`const` which will call the non-`const` function `int* Get()`. Thus, the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things

1. return type are not considered in overload resolution
2. Const ness of method is considered in over load resolution

If you remove const in second method, compiler will complain about ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered return type is not considered. So I see 3 possible solutions:

1 make it part of function signature:

```
class B {
public:
   void Get( int *&refptr );
   void Get( int &refval ) const;
};

int main(){
  B b;
  int refval2 = 0;
  b.Get( refval2 ); 
  int* pval2 = nullptr;
  b.Get( pval2 ); 
}
```

but this produces pretty ugly code, so you better use method 2 or 3 -

2 use different function names, this is pretty obvious

3 use ignored parameter:

```
class B {
public:
   int *Get( nullptr_t );
   const int &Get() const;
};

int main(){
  B b;
  const int &refval2 = b.Get();
  int* pval2 = b.Get( nullptr ); 
}
```

Comment: Alternative: Proxy return objects: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/445c96a2e05c881b

Comment: @MooingDuck it is your idea, you should submit your own answer.

Comment: @Slava: haha I was also thinking that. upped. Mooing Duck: I found Proxy class also interesting.

Comment: @Slava: It's an alternative to solving the problem, but isn't directly related to "why is the int get called instead of the const int?" So the question is about _why_ he's getting those results.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the compiler thinks the two Get() functions are the same. If you create two identical functions with only varying return types, the compiler has no idea which function you want to use. To fix the problem, change the name of one or both of the Get() functions; say GetXPtr() and GetX().

Comment: The compiler actually knows which function it wants to use, but can't because the return type is wrong.