# Functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded

Tags: android, c++, sdk, android-ndk, c++builder

**Note:** Although question is duplicate, but current answers lacks details, so I wanted to post another one.

I'm using C++Builder developed by Embarcadero.

For Windows, it compiles fine.

For Android, it shows the following error:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Building Project3.cbproj (Debug, Android)
bccaarm command line for "Project3PCH1.h"
  c:\program files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\bccaarm.exe -cc1 -D _DEBUG -output-dir .\Android\Debug -isysroot 
  C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r15c\sysroot -idirafter =\usr\include -idirafter =\usr\include\arm-linux-androideabi -idirafter 
  C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r15c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include -idirafter 
  C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r15c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -idirafter 
  C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r15c\sources\android\native_app_glue -I C:\Users\gray\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects -I "c:\program 
  files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\android\fmx" -isystem "c:\program files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include" -isystem "c:\program 
  files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\android\rtl" -isystem "c:\program files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\android\fmx" -isystem "c:\program 
  files\embarcadero\studio\20.0\include\android\crtl" -isystem C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\hpp\Android 
  -debug-info-kind=standalone -fborland-extensions -fborland-auto-refcount -nobuiltininc -nostdsysteminc -triple thumbv7-none-linux-androideabi 
  -emit-pch -mconstructor-aliases -masm-verbose -target-abi aapcs-linux -target-cpu cortex-a8 -nostdinc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fexceptions 
  -fcxx-exceptions -munwind-tables -mstackrealign -fno-spell-checking -x c++ -std=c++11 -O0 -fmath-errno -tU -o .\Android\Debug\Project3PCH1.pch 
  Project3PCH1.h 
[bccaarm Error] string.h(664): functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  string.h(50): previous declaration is here
[bccaarm Error] string.h(680): functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  string.h(69): previous declaration is here
[bccaarm Error] string.h(697): functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  string.h(89): previous declaration is here
[bccaarm Error] string.h(711): functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  string.h(118): previous declaration is here
[bccaarm Error] string.h(729): functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  string.h(155): previous declaration is here
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:18.3
```

[Here is `strings.h`](https://rentry.co/86c6e)

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Screenshots aren't acceptable. Also, please link to the duplicate you're referring to and explain *clearly* why your question is different.

Comment: [Must read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438)!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature

Comment: Looks like your project includes two different implementation of a standard library header, or including them with slightly different configurations. This doesn't seem like a language question. It looks like there is a problem with your project's configuration. Seems to me like a compiler or IDE usage problem.

Comment: when an ansewr lacks details, you should ask for clarification on the answer, not write a duplicate question

Comment: @cigien and Marek Really Sorry, I added strings.h code. And other code are default generated by c++ builder, No changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my bet is that you need to use "Preprocessor directives" in your code and indicate platforms

[How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: Are you magician ? It worked. `#ifdef _WIN32
const void ...
#endif`

Comment: Although it compiles fine, but still, I'm NOT sure whether this correct way ? and why c++ builder won't do this itself ?

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz it's a way to work on the same "project & source files" and have it compile on all platforms and/or compilers. otherwise you would maintain several projects doing the same thing. witch would complicate stuff a lot if multi platform is desired.

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz It would have helped to see the actual app code you were having trouble compiling. FYI, Embarcadero's documentation shows you how to use `#if` to detect each compiler, eg: [Writing C++ Code for BCC32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/BCC32#Writing_C.2B.2B_Code_for_BCC32), [Writing C++ Code for BCC32C and BCC32X](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers#Writing_C.2B.2B_Code_for_BCC32C_and_BCC32X), [Writing C++ Code for BCCAARM](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/BCCAARM#Writing_C.2B.2B_Code_for_BCCAARM)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Actually, I didn't change a single line of code. The project files are hello world automatically generated by builder. And sure, I will have read.