# static_cast<int>(foo) vs. (int)foo

Tags: c++, casting

Could somebody please elaborate on the differences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use static\_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The difference is that (int)foo can mean half a dozen different things.
It might be a static_cast (convert between statically known types),  it might be a const_cast (adding or removing const-ness), or it might be a reinterpret_cast (converting between pointer types)

The compiler tries each of them until it finds one that works. Which means that it may not always pick the one you expect, so it can become a subtle source of bugs.

Further, static_cast is a lot easier to search for or do search/replace on.

Comment: C-style casts can't do "safe" downcasting like dynamic_cast, only "unsafe" downcasting like static_cast.

Comment: Also, I put "safe" and "unsafe" in quotes because nothing in C++ is truly safe.

Comment: " (int)foo ... might be a dynamic_cast (downcasting to derived class)"

Not true. (int)foo will never turn into a dynamic cast.

Comment: Excellent answer, I`ve finally understood it!

Comment: Is (int)foo the same as int(foo)?

Answer (score 11):

Look at what [Stroustrup has to say about that](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast), including the following:

> Because the C-style cast (T) can be used to express many logically different operations, the compiler has only the barest chance to catch misuses. [...]
>
> The "new-style casts" were introduced to give programmers a chance to state their intentions more clearly and for the compiler to catch more errors. [...]

In particular, C++ makes the distinction between `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`:

> The idea is that conversions allowed by static_cast are somewhat less likely to lead to errors than those that require reinterpret_cast. In principle, it is possible to use the result of a static_cast without casting it back to its original type, whereas you should always cast the result of a reinterpret_cast back to its original type before using it to ensure portability.

Answer (score 1):

(int) foo compares most to c++ `reinterpret_cast<int>`, i.e. no checks on the validity of the cast.

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t280611-reinterpretcastltgt-v-staticcastltgt.html expains the difference between static_cast and reinterpret_cast

Comment: No, it compares to a combination of all the C++ casts. It'll perform the first type of cast that's valid.

Comment: True, except for dynamic_cast is not included.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the problem with (int)foo is that it probably falls through to reinterpret_cast<foo> most times? So you don't actually get the benefit of static type checking.

Comment: This answer is wrong. reinterpret_cast can, as other c++ casts, do only very little compared to a c-style cast.