# Xcode 'invalid conversion' when using objective-c++

Tags: xcode, macos

So if I run my program with the implementation as .m it works fine. Just changing it to .mm causes this line…

```
CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
```

to throw this error…

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'CGContext*'
```

Anyone have any ideas why just changing that would make it blow up, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not allow implicit type casting from `void*`. In this case, the implicit converstion from `void*` (the return type of `-[NSGraphicsContext graphicsPort]`) a `CGContextRef` is illegal. You can make the conversion explicit like this:

```
CGContextRef myContext = static_cast<CGContextRef>([[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-staticcastintx-instead-of-intx) SO question for a discussion of the C++ `static_cast` operator.

Answer (score 1):

C allows converting void * to arbitrary type, C++ does not.
Once your file is .mm it is compiled as C++:

```
cristi:tmp diciu$ cat test.c
int main()
{
    char * t = "test";
    void * m = t;
    char * g;

    g=m;

}

cristi:tmp diciu$ g++ test.c
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’

cristi:tmp diciu$ gcc test.c
```

To fix, cast to proper type, i.e. explicitly cast "void *" to "CGContext *".