# What is the most correct way to compare float to a specific NAN value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, equality, ieee-754

NaNs can potentially have many different binary representations, which can often be used to provide more information about, say, what caused the NaN. Any IEEE 32-bit float in the format of `x111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` is a NaN. Also, any comparison between 2 NaNs (of potentially different binary value) evaluates to false.

So given two floats:

```
float a = NaN1;
float b = NaN2;
```

Both are NaN, but may have different values for the `x` bits above, what is the most correct way to compare their binary contents (i.e. check that they are the same *type* of NaN)?

The most obvious way to me is perform c-style casts like: `*(uint32_t*)&a == *(uint32_t*)&b` **however**, the size of a float is not guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Comment: For float to integer conversions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544394/c-floating-point-to-integer-type-conversions

Comment: What non-32-bit size floats that support NaNs are you expecting to encounter?  I think it's unlikely that you'll encounter any non-IEEE 754 format that supports NaNs in practice.  I suppose it's possible that `float` could be the 64-bit IEEE 754 double-precision type, though that would be a bit perverse.

Comment: @MarkDickinson This is code for an embedded application. My main target is the Raspberry Pi, but I aim to support any semi-powerful microcontroller with a c compiler. I would be totally unsurprised to come across a 16-bit half-precision type float. I can't imagine such an architecture where the default float will not be 16, 32 or 64 bits over the next decade, but I prefer to avoid unnecessary constraints when practical.

Comment: Ah yes, 16-bit would do it.  Thanks.

Comment: Casting a pointer to a `uint32_t *` is UB per strict-aliasing rules.  `mmecmp`, as the answerer said, is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the second most obvious is to use `memcmp()`, which is the standard function to compare two blocks of memory bit for bit:

```
const bool equal = memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof a) == 0;
```

Also, as suggested in a comment, it's a good idea to verify that the sizes are the same:

```
const bool equal = (sizeof a == sizeof b) && (memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof a) == 0);
```

I'm not sure using `static_assert()` is a win here, but I'm not a C++11 expert, either.

Comment: Since this is C++, you can add a `static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b))`.

Comment: Seems like overkill, but it should solve all portability issues. I wonder if a modern gcc is capable of optimizing that to a simple int or long comparison in the common cases where sizeof(float) <= sizeof(int).

Comment: @Wallacoloo It is capable of that. `memcmp` is an intrinsic on all  major compilers I'm aware of.