# Is it not type safe if you are allowed to assign an int to a float (or vice-versa)?

Tags: c++, c, type-safety

Based on what I know about type safety, a type safe language does not allow you to assign a variable of one type to a variable of a different type (unless you perform an explicit conversion). But in `C` and `C++` I can do the following:

```
int i = 12345;
float f = i;    // this is allowed
```

Is this operation considered not type safe?

Comment: It doesn't means any conversion is prohibited. There're still implicit conversions being allowed.

Comment: This is allowed in C and C++. Use whatever words you like to describe it...

Comment: In C++ you can use braces to avoid implicit conversions that might lose precision, e.g. `float f = { i };`

Comment: Other duplicates & related: [C++ implicit conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/867462/514235) ... and ... [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000/514235) ... and ... [C++ floating point to integer type conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2544394/514235)

Comment: yes, it is a violation of type safety for the sake of convenience.

Comment: Sure, given that definition of "type safe", C and C++ and Java and a bunch of other languages are not "type safe".

Answer (score 1):

> [..] a type safe language does not allow you to assign a variable of one type to a variable of a different type (unless you perform an explicit conversion).

I don't think that this would be a good definition. Rather I'd say that a type safe language does not allow operations specific to / designed for a type `X` to be performed on a value of a other type `Y` if those two types are not considered compatible under some metric. That's what's known as strong typing (not to be confused with static typing).

> Is this operation considered not type safe?

It's a well defined (albeit implicit) conversion from one type to another.

What seems to be bugging you is the part that this conversion is implicit and not explicit. I don't know of a distinct "term" / word to describe that a language allows implicit conversions, though.

That said, C++ surely is not type safe in all respects.