# FPU exception when converting float into int32_t

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-cast

I have a seemingly simple goal: I want to convert a float into an integer-type that is exactly 32 bit wide.
The code I am posting works on my windows machine, but not on the Linux device I am trying to run the code in the end.
I have tried this first:

```
float a;
a = /*some real number, for example 1.08825e+11*/;
if (!isfinite(a)){
 return -1;
}
int32_t b;
b = static_cast<int32_t> (a);
```

Which does not work -the programs just crashes with this information in the command window:

> Runtime received SIGFPE (address: 0xb62cd3b7 reason: floating-point
>   invalid operation)

Then I have found [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544394/c-floating-point-to-integer-type-conversions) in another question on stack overflow that safely converts float into int-data types and have tried to adopt the function for my needs. This is my version:

```
template <class FloatType>
int32_t safeFloatToDINT(const FloatType& num) {
    //check if float fits into int32_t
    if (std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::digits < std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::digits) {
        // check if float is smaller than max int32_t
        if ((num < static_cast<FloatType>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())) &&
            (num > static_cast<FloatType>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min()))) {
            return static_cast<int32_t>(num); //safe to cast
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Unsafe conversion of value:" << num << std::endl;
            //NaN is not defined for int32_t return the largest int32_t value
            return std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
        }
    }
    else {
        //It is safe to cast
        return static_cast<int32_t>(num);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `b = safeFloatToDINT(a);`
throws the FPU exception, too. I have also just tried writing `b = (int32_t)a;` but that does not work either. I would like to know how I can take my float variable and safely convert it into an integer type that spans 32 bit.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never initialize `a`

Comment: `a` is uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. My program initializes a always and checks for its validity. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: `static_cast` is unnecessary, float to integer is an implicit conversion. It probably crashes because of an integer division by 0 elsewhere - that is what causes `SIGFPE`. Run it under a debugger to find the line which causes the crash.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin Thank you for your comment. The conversion line is exactly where the program crashes. there is no division involved. In the second approach the line `(num < static_cast<FloatType>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())` crashes. If I use `double` instead of `float` the second approach works. I still do not understand the underlying problem so that I can prevent a even bigger number to crash the `double` version of the code as well.

Comment: @MertY What platform and CPU?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This is using a  Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU E680 on a Linux device

Comment: What does `std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)` return?