# int to unsigned int conversion

Tags: c++

I'm just amazed to know that I can't convert signed to unsigned int by casting!

```
int i = -62;
unsigned int j = (unsigned int)i;
```

I thought I already knew this since I started to use casts, but I can't do it!

Comment: what would you logically expect this cast to do?

Comment: My bad guys, But I appreciate the explanation. I was trying to convert signed char -62 to unsigned int and expecting to get a value of 194 (x.x)

Comment: Um... Casting? Conversions between integer types do not require casts in C++. They are *standard conversions*, and they are performed implicitly. In your case you could simply do `unsigned int j = i;` for exactly the same effect.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine ([live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WRWFrs)). Could you edit the question so that it does not imply, that it does not compile? It's misleading.

Comment: A litle nitpicking, but for the newbies out there, in C++ you should not use c casts `(unsigned int)i` any more. use `static_cast<unsigned int>(i)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/103868/1614903 for elaboration.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can convert an `int` to an `unsigned int`.  The conversion is valid and well-defined.

Since the value is negative, `UINT_MAX + 1` is added to it so that the value is a valid unsigned quantity.  (Technically, 2<sup>N</sup> is added to it, where N is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type.)

In this case, since `int` on your platform has a width of 32 bits, 62 is subtracted from 2<sup>32</sup>, yielding 4,294,967,234.

Comment: @SIFE the integer being converted is -62... so when you add UINT_MAX (which is 2^32) to it, it becomes a subtraction of 62.

Answer (score 50):

**Edit**: As has been noted in the other answers, the standard actually guarantees that "*the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)*". So even if your platform did not store signed ints as two's complement, the behavior would be the same.

---

Apparently your signed integer -62 is stored in two's complement ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) on your platform:

62 as a 32-bit integer written in binary is

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110
```

To compute the two's complement (for storing -62), first invert all the bits

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0001
```

then add one

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0010
```

And if you interpret this as an unsigned 32-bit integer (as your computer will do if you cast it), you'll end up with 4294967234 :-)

Answer (score 9):

This conversion is well defined and will yield the value `UINT_MAX - 61`.  On a platform where `unsigned int` is a 32-bit type (most common platforms, these days), this is precisely the value that others are reporting.  Other values are possible, however.

The actual language in the standard is

> If the destination type is unsigned,
>   the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the
>   source integer (modulo 2^n where n is
>   the number of bits used to represent
>   the unsigned type).

Comment: As the standard has a clear definition.Why other values are still possible？

Comment: The value is different for different sizes of integers. That's why the standard talks about "congruent" and "number of bits".

Answer (score 5):

i=-62 . If you want to convert it to a unsigned representation. It would be 4294967234 for a 32 bit integer. 
A simple way would be to

```
num=-62
unsigned int n;
n = num
cout<<n;
```

> 4294967234

Answer (score 4):

Since we know that `i` is an `int`, you can just go ahead and *unsigneding* it!

This would do the trick:

```
int i = -62;
unsigned int j = unsigned(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

From c++17, one can use `make_unsigned_t`

```
auto uint_variable = std::make_unsigned_t<int>(-62); //4294967234
```

Answer (score 3):

with a little help of math

```
#include <math.h>
int main(){
  int a = -1;
  unsigned int b;
  b = abs(a);
}
```

Comment: @chad: There's absolutely no difference in specification of signed -> unsigned conversion between C and C++. It works identically in both languages.

Comment: Oh man, I accidentally just deleted my comment. Sorry! It originally said something along the lines of this wouldn't work because the difference in twos compliment representation. I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote this, you're absolutely correct.