# additional > after #include and still valid

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have noticed that I wrote by mistake

```
#include <vector>> //Notice the additional > after <vector>
```

My code compiled well without any problem. How is this possible?

P.S. I am on MSVS 2015

**Edit:**

The compiler actually raise a warning about it. However, should not it be an error rather than an warning by the standard?

Comment: GCC and Clang also accept this code, with a warning.

Comment: 1>c:\users\starl1ght\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\stack\stack\main.cpp(5): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

Comment: Sorry I did notice the warning.. but shouldn't it be an error? does the standard allow to write whatever after the include statement ?

Comment: It's ill-formed according to the standard (as best as I can tell), but that's not your question.

Comment: The standard doesn't make a difference between an error and a warning, it just says that [the compiler must issue a diagnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807404/does-the-c-standard-specify-that-for-some-cases-the-compiling-should-fail-with).

Comment: @BoPersson got it now.. thanks

Comment: Apparently you can write anything after preprocessor directive and the compiler will only issue warning.

Comment: do you still remember the old days of visual c++ 6.0 where we can write: `??=include<>` instead of `#include<>`?

Comment: @Raindrop7: the `??=` is a trigraph for `#`.  You can also use `%:` as a digraph for `#`.  AFAIK, even C++14 hasn't eliminated trigraphs, but C++17 will.  GCC doesn't recognize them unless you insist (`--trigraphs`).