# Why can I pass an int with a value higher than 127 into a char array, but not directly?

Tags: c++, char, byte, unsigned, signed

I understand that a char value cannot be represented as 176, but some byte systems are unsigned (0-255) while others are signed (-128 to 127). In this case I'm working with unsigned, so I just wanted to create a simple byte message array, but I get this error when trying to place a higher value than 127, but if I declare it as an int first it avoids the error. Can someone explain in detail why this works?

**Method 1: Doesn't work. I get this error: narrowing conversion of ‘176’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’**

```
char m1[3]{ 176, 118, 1 };
```

**Method 2: This works**

```
int b1 = 176;
char m1[3]{ b1, 118, 1 };
```

Comment: Note that `char` may be `signed` on some platforms and `unsigned` on other platforms.

Comment: Error or warning?

Comment: I get a compiler error

Comment: You probably have warnings as errors enabled. If I had to guess, the compiler is able to generate a warning in the first case because it is a literal, in the second case, it doesn't know if the value of b1 might have changed. Just a guess ...

Comment: I still get a warning [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0dbd9775a09e61a) and if you use `-Werror` it'll become an error

Comment: Interesting.. I tested it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6cZKOKizzKGYCBTq), and 1st example is an error, while 2nd one is a warning, with exactly the same text.. I wonder why those 2 examples are different to the compiler..

Comment: This might not be an XY problem, but I think it's related. Why do you want to put a value greater than 127 into a `signed char`? Why not declare your array as `unsigned char` instead?

Comment: A com port system I'm using can only write with signed char arrays. To be clear the messages are going through and work

Comment: @TimRandall "_Why do you want to put a value greater than 127 into a `signed char`?_" How do you know that the `char` on their platform is signed?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The first array the compiler knows without a doubt the element is to large, so it is a hard error.  The second array it knows an `int` is to big so you get a warning.  Both of these are correct per the standard as a error == warning == diagnostic message

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I was assuming that the compiler wouldn't generate "narrowing conversion of ‘176’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’" when initializing an `unsigned char`

Comment: On my system, I get no warning for the 2nd method and it is writing the correct byte message to my device, so I was wondering why my 2nd method works correctly.

Comment: @karamazovbros What compiler are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, that makes sense. Thank you. Probably me knowing that it's too large anyway (seeing the assingment just above it), led me to an assumption, that compiler would know this information as well :/

Comment: @karamazovbros "_On my system, I get no warning for the 2nd method_" Did you enable warnings? By, for example, adding `-Wall` to compiler options?

Comment: I'm compiling through the Unreal Engine, so it might hide warnings by default?

Comment: That is possible.  If the have an option for `-Werror` you should use it.  It will turn warnings into errors.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is a mixed bag that narrowing conversions can be both warnings and errors depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using curly braces for initialization (aka "uniform initialization") then narrowing conversions are not allowed. Otherwise they are and the value is just silently truncated.

Most compilers have warning options that you can enable that will catch many (but not all) instances where truncation happens. They usually also have options that can turn such warnings into errors.
You should use those options.

If you want to work with bytes then [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is arguably the correct type to use. Or (if you cannot use that) [std::uint8_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Answer (score 1):

Both cases are ill-formed but as I explain in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685448/1708801) ill-formed only requires a diagnostic. Whether that diagnostic is a warning or an error is up to the implementation. So this is very much a conforming result.

For example for this case gcc produces an error for the first but only a warning for the second ([see it live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PoMBT9)):

```
error: narrowing conversion of '176' from 'int' to 'char'  [-Wnarrowing]
    2 |     char m1[3]{ 176, 118, 1 };
      |                             ^
warning: narrowing conversion of 'b1' from 'int' to 'char' [-Wnarrowing]

    5 |    char m2[3]{ b1, 118, 1 };
      |                           ^
```

This is allowed by the standard, I will quote the relevent section from [this gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783#c4) on this:

> The standard only requires that "a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message" so compiling the program with a warning is allowed.  As Andrew said, -Werror=narrowing allows you to make it an error if you want.
>
> G++ 4.6 gave an error but it was changed to a warning intentionally for 4.7 because many people (myself included) found that narrowing conversions where one of the most commonly encountered problems when trying to compile large C++03 codebases as C++11.  Previously well-formed code such as char c[] = { i, 0 }; (where i will only ever be within the range of char) caused errors and had to be changed to char c[] = { (char)i, 0 }

With both gcc and clang you can turn all warnings into errors by using `-Werror`.

Answer (score 0):

Typical char ranges on most systems:

- Type: **char**, Range: **-127 to 127** or **0 to 255**
- Type: **unsigned char**, Range: **0 to 255**
- Type: **signed char**, Range: **-127 to 127**

Whether `char` is *signed* or *unsigned* is implementation-defined. You can check using `std::is_signed<char>()`. In your case, it's implicitly *signed*, and the compiler detected that you are implicitly converting from a positive integer (10110000 = 176) to a signed character value (where 10110000 is -90). The warning won't be generated if the values are less than or equal to 127 (try it!).
If you want to avoid the implicit conversion (narrowing conversion), you can explicitly specify that it's *unsigned*:

```
unsigned char m1[3]{ 176, 118, 1 };
```

If you want to use *signed characters*, you should preferably use the `signed` modifier, rather than relying on the implementation:

```
signed char m1[3]{ b, 118, 1 }; // where b is less than or equal to 127
```

With the {}-initialization, the compiler should - at least - diagnose it as a warning, which makes the program ill-formed. But again, that depends on the compiler and options used. If you go to https://gcc.godbolt.org/ and compile your code with different compilers/options, you could see the difference.

Some examples:

For the following code:

```
char m1[3] = {176, 118, 1 };
```

- with **x86-64 gcc 6.1** you get an error: `error: narrowing conversion of '176' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]`. However, when you use the flag `-Wno-narrowing` you don't get it, but still, your program is ill-formed and you don't want that.
- with **x86-64 gcc 4.8.1** you get no errors, no warnings. However, when using, for example, the options `-Wno-narrowing` or `-Werror=narrowing`, you can see that it's rejected with a warning or error respectively.

With the code:

```
int b1 = 176;
char m1[3] = {b1, 118, 1 };
```

You get a different behavior with different compiler versions, but still, the program is ill-formed.

In general, using options like `-Wnarrowing`, `-Wall`, or `-Werror=narrowing` with whatever version (I guess, I didn't check all of them) of the compiler, should point out the narrowing conversion, which means that your program is ill-formed and you don't want that.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Do note that what you have given as the range is a minimum.  Nothing stops char from being 32 bits and having a much larger range.