# Why doesn't my compiler recognise "Bond() = default;"?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please look at this code

```
class Bond
{
    public:
        Bond(int payments_per_year, int period_lengths_in_months);
        Bond() = default;

    private:
        const int payments_per_year;
        const int period_length_in_months;
    };

int main()
{
    Bond b; // Error here
}
```

When attempting to compile I get an error:

> error C2280: 'Bond::Bond(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function".

It's not a "rule of 3" violation since I've added the default constructor back.

Why doesn't the compiler recognise `Bond() = default;`?

Comment: I have other error `uninitialized const member in 'const int'`. When you initialize constant member no more error produced.

Comment: Rule of three violation has got nothing to do with the problem at all, regardless of the presence of a (default) constructor.

Comment: `= default`ing a special member doesn't mean that it exists, but that the implicit one is generated. If the implicitly generated one doesn't exist, then you get this.

Comment: Even though we are quite likely to recognize the compiler from the error cited in this case, any question with "why my compiler" would benefit greatly from indicating *which* compiler, and *which* version of it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are being affected by section [[class.default.ctor]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#2) of the draft C++ standard (or [[class.ctor]p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.ctor#5.3) in C++11) which says:

> A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>   ...
>   - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no brace-or-equal-initializer does not have a user-provided default constructor,
>   ...

They possible key to fixing your issue is with the phrase *with no brace-or-equal-initializer* so if you provide *brace-or-equal-initializer* that will fix your issue e.g.:

```
const int payments_per_year{12};
const int period_length_in_months{48};
```

[brace-or-equal-initializer](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:brace-or-equal-initializer) does not require braces, we can see this the grammar:

```
brace-or-equal-initializer:
    = initializer-clause
    braced-init-list
```

but using uniform initialization has some advantages such as making [narrowing conversions ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685448/1708801) that it is worth getting used to using them.

Both gcc and clang provide more meaningful diagnostics for this [see the live godbolt session](https://godbolt.org/z/ghX21z). Sometimes it can be helpful to try your code on multiple compilers, especially if you have a minimal test case like this e.g. clang says:

```
 warning: explicitly defaulted default constructor is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
    Bond() = default;
    ^
 note: default constructor of 'Bond' is implicitly deleted because field 'payments_per_year' of const-qualified type 'const int' would not be initialized
    const int payments_per_year;
              ^
...
```

Comment: It may be worth filing a bug report, the diagnostic could be more meaningful.

Comment: Some examples of [uniform initialization catching bugs that came up recently](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1058737227184844800

Answer (score 51):

The default constructor is *suppressed* since there are constant members that need to be explicitly initialised.

Therefore, due to that suppression, writing `Bond() = default` does *not* reintroduce the default constructor.

(You can see this effect by removing all the constructors in the class - you still can't instantiate a `b`.)

If you drop the `const` from the members then all will be well; although another alternative is to supply a *brace-or-equal-initializer* for each `const` member;

```
const int payments_per_year = 2;
const int period_length_in_months = 6;
```

for example.

Answer (score 24):

Another fix, is to specify a default value in the declaration of the constants:

```
const int payments_per_year = {12};
```

This can still be overridden by the valued constructor, but allows the default constructor to proceed.

This is also a very flexible way to simplify your multiple constructor cases.

Comment: Do we need the braces?

Comment: Equals *and* braces is definitely weird. Not sure what it actually means. Init from an initializer_list? Anyway: in-class member initializers are – well – initializers, and the syntax rules for initialization apply. That means either = or {}.

Comment: @PaulSanders no, you don't need braces but uniform initialization has a lot of advantages such as making narrowing conversions ill-formed that it is worth getting used to using them. See my update below.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: You could keep the braces and drop the equal though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that is exactly what I did in my answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yep, and that's part of the reason why I much prefer your answer (the other being actual standard quotes).

Comment: You are right.. the braces and the equals are not both needed. It is a bad habit I got into when adding this "hey guys a new feature" to my code. It sure makes these default constructions stand out nicel.y