# Cast signed char to unsigned int in C

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, signed

Can anyone explain to me why the following code outputs -50 even though it is being cast to an unsigned int?

```
int main()
{
  signed char byte = -50;
  unsigned int n;

  n = (unsigned int) byte;

  printf("n: %d", n);
}
```

output: -50

Comment: replace **%d** with **%u** for unsigned int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast is correct, but you are printing it incorrectly. `%d` in `printf()` is for `int`, change it to:

```
printf("n: %u", n);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I feel dumb :P Didn't realize that. I have grown so used to working in Java and C# forgot a lot of c syntax.

Comment: It is not a correct answer ! The printf will display 4294967246

Answer (score 6):

Assigning `-50` to `unsigned int` causes the integer to wrap around, and this wrapped around `unsigned int` has the same bits set as the `signed int` corresponding to `-50` in the twos complement representation that is used by almost every computer.

Now, `printf` is a function with a variable number of arguments that it interprets according to the format string. The format `%d` is for *signed* `int`s and `printf` has no way of knowing that the corresponding argument is actually an `unsigned int` (because you told it otherwise). So the bits get interpreted as though it were `signed int` and you get `-50`.

Answer (score 2):

Even with `printf("n: %u", n);` , you are not going to get `50`.

see the link
[int to unsigned int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975340/int-to-unsigned-int-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

With your statement:

```
printf("n: %d", n);
```

you are casting it to "Signed decimal integer"

if you try

```
std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
```

you will see that you won't get **-50**

Comment: That's C++, the question is tagged with C.