# Avoiding overflow boost container

Tags: c++

I was looking through some of boost container memory pool code and came across the following which I do not understand, complete source [.cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/container/blob/develop/src/pool_resource.cpp#L71) [.h](https://github.com/boostorg/container/blob/develop/include/boost/container/detail/pool_resource.hpp)

```
//Limit max value
std::size_t blocks_per_chunk
    = boost::container::dtl::min_value(max_blocks_per_chunk, next_blocks_per_chunk);
//Avoid overflow
blocks_per_chunk
    = boost::container::dtl::min_value(blocks_per_chunk, std::size_t(-1)/pool_block);
```

Specifically I do not understand how the second line of code "avoids overflow". 
`blocks_per_chunk` is already set to be the minimum of next and `max_blocks_per_chunk`. So this should already be in a valid range.

What does dividing `-1` by pool_block do in this situation?

Comment: side note: it's not dividing `-1`. Because `std::size_t` is unsigned and unsigned has wraparound behavior `std::size_t(-1)` is the maximum value held by `std::size_t`, a.k.a. `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `std::size_t(-1) / pool_block` is the largest `std::size_t` value which, when multiplied by `pool_block`, will not overflow a `std::size_t`. (Because `std::size_t` is unsigned, and because of [how signed-to-unsigned integer conversions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975340/int-to-unsigned-int-conversion), `std::size_t(-1)` is the largest representable `std::size_t` value, i.e., equivalent to [`std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) but a little shorter to type.)

I suspect the intent is to restrict `blocks_per_chunk` to values that won't cause overflows in subsequent math operations using this variable. Indeed, the following code comes right after:

```
//Minimum block size is at least max_align, so all pools allocate sizes that are multiple of max_align,
//meaning that all blocks are max_align-aligned.
char *p = static_cast<char *>(block_slist_base_t::allocate(blocks_per_chunk*pool_block, mr));
```

Here, `blocks_per_chunk * pool_block` would overflow if `blocks_per_chunk > std::size_t(-1) / pool_block`.