# Modified Fibbonaci C++ getting a large negative number

Tags: c++, fibonacci

Ok so, I'm doing hackerrank's Fibonacci modified question. I am able to solve this question only when the iteration goes to 8 anything pass that and it starts returning a large negative number. I thought this was because of an integer overflow so I changed my types to unsigned long long yet the problems still persist. Any help is appreciated.

Link to original problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified/problem

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int modFib(unsigned t1, unsigned t2, unsigned n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return t1;
        } 
        else if (n == 2) {
            return t2;
        } else {
            return modFib(t1, t2, n-2) + (modFib(t1, t2, n-1) * modFib(t1, t2, n-1));
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        cout << modFib(0, 1, 10) << endl;
        return 0;
    }

//Expected output is 84266613096281243382112
//I get -1022889632
```

Comment: you forgot the return type - also `unsigned` is `unsigned int` and not `unsigned long long`

Comment: These aren't regular Fibonacci numbers, so could you briefly explain the maths involved. It's hard to work out where you're going wrong when I don't know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [int to unsigned int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975340/int-to-unsigned-int-conversion)

Comment: Sorry, I linked the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, the general range of an `unsigned int` is `0 to 4,294,967,295`, so using an `unsigned int` will not be appropriate for this problem.

The expected output is actually larger than the maximum possible value of even an `unsigned long long int`, which goes from `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615`. This means that you cannot use either of these data types for this problem.

For such large values, you should look into the usage of `BigNums`.

Comment: While I'm sure you are right about the problem in this case the figures you are quoting are completely platform dependent. C++ only specifies minimum ranges that the various integer types must support.

Comment: Ok will look into BigNums and see if I can solve it then

Comment: Yea this works, however, using it in hacker rank is no go because I cant use other libraries on that website. I guess it just isn't doable in hacker rank or at least isn't practical

Comment: Why not? The implementation for a BigNum isn't extremely complicated.