# Difference between static_cast<primitive_type>(foo) and primitive_type(foo)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)
>   [In C++, why use static_cast<int>(x) instead of (int)x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)

What is the difference between `static_cast<float>(foo)` and `float(foo)`? I often see `static_cast<float>` or similar in template code to get from any integral type to some specific integral type. For example say I wanted a function to perform floating point division on any integral type. I normally see something like this:

```
template <typename T>
float float_div(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    // I normally see this
    return static_cast<float>(lhs) / static_cast<float>(rhs);

    // But I could do this
    // return float(lhs) / float(rhs); // But I could do this
}
```

Is there any advantage to using `float(lhs)` or `static_cast<float>(lhs)`? Also what is the name of the `float(lhs)` initialization/conversion?

Comment: `static_cast` stands out and shouts, "I AM PERFORMING A CAST!".

Comment: @chris: At least until it runs out of mana.

Comment: Added question: any difference to `(float) foo`?

Comment: @LukasSchmelzeisen: `(float)foo` and `float(foo)` are the same.

Comment: @LukasSchmelzeisen, That's an ill-advised C-style cast. I'm not sure if `float(foo)` and `(float)foo` are exactly the same, or have a subtle difference, but the C++ one is explicit, noticeable, and safer.

Comment: @Cat Ah, I didn't realize this was just a C-style cast.

Comment: FWIW, the official name in the C++ standard for a C-style cast is "Explicit Type Conversion (cast notation) [5.4]" and the float(lhs) variant is "Explicit Type Conversion (functional notation) [5.2.3]". They are basically equivalent to automatically doing of const_cast<> and/or static_cast<> and/or reinterpret_cast<> required to whack the source type into the target type.

Comment: @chris I don't think it is always ill-advised, especially with simple types. In pure C++, I agree but there are lots of places where integration with C and/or embedded OS's where the hard "just do it" casts are the least bad option.