# What's the Difference Between These Two Casts in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

Code sample one:

```
float i=1.1f;
int j=static_cast<int>(i);
cout << j<< endl;
```

Code sample Two:

```
float i=1.1f;
int j=(int)i;
cout << j<< endl;
```

what's the difference between these code samples about converting in c++?

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) might help you.

Comment: You can read about casting in c++. Especially about `static_cast` here.

Comment: and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213285/difference-between-static-castprimitive-typefoo-and-primitive-typefoo?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Comment: What you are doing is not conversion, it's type casting (pretending a value of one type is actually a value of another type). And in practice there's no difference between the two examples. When you start working with custom classes and inheritance, the old C-way of casting might produce different results from the C++-style casting though.