# why does this function keep crashing?

Tags: c++, hash, compression

Forethought: If it is needed then I can add the class definition.
Problem: I get a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION whenever I try to run this function in my program. I was wondering what was going on. Am I out of bounds somewhere? If I could reason it out myself I would. But I cannot figure it out alone. I'm very close to just hiring someone to do the debugging for me. It's worth my wile. So anyway, this needs to be looked over and given a little TLC. Thanks in advance!

```
int S_Rend::count(bitset<8> alpha, bitset<8> spec) {

    int bn;
    vector< bitset<8> > cnt;
    bitset<8> curr;
    int chmp;

    eta = (alpha & spec);
    theta = (alpha | spec);

    cnt[0] = eta & alpha;
    cnt[1] = eta | alpha;
    cnt[2] = eta & spec;
    cnt[3] = eta | spec;
    cnt[4] = theta & alpha;
    cnt[5] = theta | alpha;
    cnt[6] = theta & spec;
    cnt[7] = theta | spec;
    cnt[8] = cnt[0] & cnt[5];
    cnt[9] = cnt[6] | cnt[1];
    cnt[10] = cnt[2] & cnt[7];
    cnt[11] = cnt[4] | cnt[3];

    for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
        for (int j=i;j<=11;j++) {
            curr = cnt[i];
            if (cnt[j] == curr)
                bn++;
            if (bn>chmp)
                chmp=bn;
        }

    return chmp;
}

int S_Rend::s_render(ifstream& in, ofstream& out) {

    int i, n;
    int t;
    int chk;
    in >> lambda;
    in >> size;
    in >> delta;
    in >> chk;
    t=(int&)beta;
    int bn=0;

    while (size-1>=bn) {
        t=s_nop((int&)t,0);
        cred.push_back(t);
        bn++;       
    }

    if (cred[bn-1]==chk)
        cout << "\nValidity Pass... Success!" << endl;
    else {
        printf("\nValidity Pass...Fail! %u != %u",cred[cred.size()-1],chk);
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\nWriting to Buffer..." << endl;
    i=0;
    spec = lambda;
int f;
while (bn-1>=0) {
    alpha = (int&)cred[bn-1];
    f=count(alpha, spec);
    eta = (int&)f;
    spec ^= alpha ^ eta;
    btrace.push_back(f);
    cout << f << " ";
    bn--;
}

    cout << "One more second..\n";

    while (i<=bn-1) {
        delta = (int&)btrace[bn];
        out << (const char)(int&)delta;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "\nBuffer Written... Exiting..\n";
    in.close();
    out.close();
    printf("*");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you used a debugger, which statement(s) are causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables used in the statement(s)?

Comment: What are you supposed to be doing with lines like this? `delta = (int&)btrace[bn];`?  Why are you casting to an int reference?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question again and again. Also, [tag:data-mining] is *not* bitcoin mining, obviously.

Comment: You really should hire someone to fix your code then.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm casting those to bitsets. 8 bits per. So they need to be formatted just such the way I have them after casting. I tried without and got compilation problems. `delta` is a `bitset<8>`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My cygwin doesn't come with the libpython2.7.dll so I can't debug with gdb. REALLY sad that I can't. I'm very upset about that. But I bought VS 2010. And hopefully that'll help get the problems over with.

Comment: Cygwin does not install python in the default load. Run the cygwin setup program. When you get to Package selection, expand the python package group and click where it says **skip** in front of the **Python: Python Language Interpreter** package. skip should turn into the version number that's about to be installed.  Next your way through and let it install.

Comment: AH!! THANK YOU!! @user4581301 You sir are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: @user4581301 Is this an `overflow` problem? I'm doing a lot of work in it. Is it too much for my computer? The problem comes right after hitting the other function `count()`.

Comment: @thexiv Remove the casts.  What compiler error do you receive?  Whatever it is, read it carefully -- the compiler is detecting that something stinks, and you're trying to hide the stink by casting.

Comment: `vector< bitset<8> > cnt;` does not specify a size of the vector, nor do you resize to reserve any space or push_back elements. When you start indexing it, here for example: `cnt[0] = eta & alpha;` Crom only knows what will happen or where in memory the assignment will go, if it gets that far. Since you seem to know you want 12 elements in the vector, construct it with `vector< bitset<8> > cnt(12);` Read up on vectors here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much. That did the trick. Would you know if I can recursively go through the byte I have and, allowing that I'm going the other way, be able to take out the alpha and the spec from f, which is my plan?

Answer (score 2):

At this point :
    while (bn) {
    alpha = (int&)cred[bn];
    f=count(alpha, spec);

bn == size and size == cred.size() so you read ouside the vector. Assuming cred is empty at start

Comment: I changed that and it didn't work, Jerome. It's something else.

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring issue is that you're writing (and reading) from a vector with out-of-bounds indices:

```
int S_Rend::count(bitset<8> alpha, bitset<8> spec) 
{
    int bn;
    vector< bitset<8> > cnt;
    bitset<8> curr;
    int chmp;

    eta = (alpha & spec);
    theta = (alpha | spec);

    cnt[0] = eta & alpha;  // <-- Illegal access
    ...
}
```

Well, we can stop right there.

The `std::vector` is not sized, so it cannot hold any elements.  The last line assumes that `vector` can hold at least one item (item 0).  Thus this is undefined behavior.

Size the vector appropriately before accessing elements by calling `push_back`, `vector::resize`, `vector::insert`, `vector::emplace_back`, or construct the vector by issuing one of the constructors that sizes the vector in addition to constructing it.

[std::vector description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Since it seems you want 12 items, then you can construct it with 12 items.

```
int S_Rend::count(bitset<8> alpha, bitset<8> spec) 
{
    int bn;
    vector< bitset<8> > cnt(12);
    bitset<8> curr;
    int chmp;

    eta = (alpha & spec);
    theta = (alpha | spec);

    cnt[0] = eta & alpha;  // <-- ok
    ...
}
```

Also, as a debugging aid, you could have used [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `operator [ ]` to access the vector items.  Using `at()` would have immediately thrown a `std::out_of_bounds` exception indicating that you were accessing the vector with an invalid index (instead of the program continuing as if nothing is wrong).

---

The second thing that seems dubious is you casting a `std::bitset` to an int reference, or vice-versa.  As you observed, without the cast, you get an error.  Using a C-style cast to "shut the compiler up" is not a good idea, as all you're doing is bypassing the type-safety mechanism that C++ has in place at compile-time.

If the compiler says to you "this shouldn't be done", and then you override it by issuing a C-style cast, prepare to suffer the consequences if / when your program shows erratic behavior.

To properly convert between a `std::bitset` and an `int`, there are methods for this, namely `std::to_ulong`.

[How to convert from bitset to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583720/convert-bitset-to-int-in-c)

Comment: I fixed all that and she's running like a gallupin horse, hyuk. But I wonder, if I just used a `&` encryption, how would I get that back with a key? I can't find the XOR encryption destroyer.