# Generate state based on values of struct member function

Tags: c++, struct, states

I am currently trying to come up with a pretty solution that generates an integer based state, based on a struct.

```
struct status{
public:
    status();
    /**
     * @brief busy
     * true =  Currently handling a message in manual mode
     * false = Not handling 
     */
    bool busy;
    /**
     * @brief speed
     * Variable containing the current speed 
     * Speed possibilities [FAST;MEDIUM;SLOW]
     */
    int speed;
    /**
     * @brief powered
     * A boolean determining whether it is powered or not.
     * true = ON
     * false = OFF
     */
    bool powered;
    /**
     * @brief direction
     * A boolean determing the direction 
     * true = FORWARD
     * false = BACKWARDS
     */
    bool direction;

};
```

The function need to take  an instance of the struct in, and generate a unique state based on member variables.

What is a pretty solution that doesn't involve manually checking, or setting up all the possibilities an thereby generate the state?

Comment: So you want to `hash` this `struct`?

Comment: hmmm... Interesting... Well yeah a hash function.. If the key generated is an integer..

Comment: Just a suggestion, not an answer to your questions. When `true` and `false` need explanation and you only have a limited number of values for speed you can use enums. Names like `FORWARD` and `BACKWARDS` are easier readable in code and people do not need to look up which value is which.

Comment: Ohh.. yeah I made it as defines.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Padding bytes are not initialized so `memcpy` will be error-prone

Comment: @GuyGreer True, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a bitset *(either [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) or an unsigned numerical type)* to represent your unique state.

You will need:

- 1 bit for `busy`.
- 1 bit for `powered`.
- 1 bit for `direction`.
- 2 bits for `speed`.

In total, you will need 5 bits to represent all possible combinations.

Example:

```
auto status::hash() const noexcept
{
    std::bitset<5> b;
    b |= speed; // assumes only the last two bits in `speed` are used
    b.set(4, busy);
    b.set(3, powered);
    b.set(2, direction);
    return b;
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IMyz1FAsvyKFD3IU)

Comment: Will any mismatch occur when i convert the `std::bitset` back to `int8`?

Comment: @CarltonBanks: there should be no mismatch. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583720/convert-bitset-to-int-in-c) for a conversion example. Alternatively, you can use the same logic to do the bitwise arithmetic directly on an `std::uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as `std::bitset`, but you could store the entire struct in a single byte using a bit field:

```
struct status {
public:
    status(Busy busy, Speed speed, Powered powered, Direction direction)
        : busy{busy}, speed{speed}, powered{powered}, direction{direction}, pad{0} {};

    Busy busy : 1;
    Speed speed : 2;
    Powered powered : 1;
    Direction direction : 1;
    unsigned char pad : 3; // pad to 8 bits
};
```

Full program:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

#define ENUM_MACRO3(name, v1, v2, v3)\
    enum class name : unsigned char { v1, v2, v3};\
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, name var) {\
        switch (var){\
            case name::v1: return os << #v1;\
            case name::v2: return os << #v2;\
            case name::v3: return os << #v3;\
        }\
        return os;\
    }

#define ENUM_MACRO2(name, v1, v2)\
    enum class name : unsigned char { v1, v2};\
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, name var) {\
        switch (var){\
            case name::v1: return os << #v1;\
            case name::v2: return os << #v2;\
        }\
        return os;\
    }

ENUM_MACRO3(Speed, fast, medium, slow)
ENUM_MACRO2(Busy, handling, not_handling)
ENUM_MACRO2(Powered, on, off)
ENUM_MACRO2(Direction, forwards, backwards)

struct status {
public:
    status(Busy busy, Speed speed, Powered powered, Direction direction)
        : busy{busy}, speed{speed}, powered{powered}, direction{direction}, pad{0} {};

    Busy busy : 1;
    Speed speed : 2;
    Powered powered : 1;
    Direction direction : 1;
    unsigned char pad : 3; // pad to 8 bits
};

int main()
{
    status s{Busy::not_handling,Speed::slow,Powered::off,Direction::backwards};

    std::cout << "Data has size of " << sizeof(status) << '\n';
    std::cout << "busy :" << s.busy << '\n';
    std::cout << "speed :" << s.speed << '\n';
    std::cout << "powered :" << s.powered << '\n';
    std::cout << "direction :" << s.direction << '\n';

    unsigned char val = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(s);
    unsigned int num{val};
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    std::bitset<8> bs{num};
    std::cout << bs << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Data has size of 1
busy :not_handling
speed :slow
powered :off
direction :backwards
29
00011101
```

---

Some points to keep in mind:

- [Bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) are not portable. Another implementation may:

  - Use more than one byte.
  - Reverse the bits.
  - Introduce padding to align the bits differently.
- The program above is breaking the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

  - So it would probably be best to produce the hash with `std::bitset` by setting the bits directly in a safe way.
- Bit fields are slower.