# Char variable value not being displayed

Tags: c++, char, outputstream

Excuse the vague title ( I didn't know how to address the issue). Anyways, within my code I explicitly declared a few variables, two being signed/unsigned **int** variables, and the others being signed/unsigned **char** type variables.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int number = UINT_MAX;
    signed int number2 = INT_MAX;
    unsigned char U = UCHAR_MAX;
    signed char S = CHAR_MAX;

    std::cout << number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " << sizeof(number) <<       std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << number2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " <<sizeof(number2) << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << U << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " << sizeof(U) << std::endl
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << S << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " <<sizeof(S) << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry the code is scrambled due to excessive length, but my issue is that my **char** variables are not "printing" to my output. It outputs their size in bytes, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to work. Also, The second **char** variable (signed (S)) prints what appears to look like a triangle, but nothing else.

Comment: Cast them to int to display the value rather than the ascii character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::cout << (int)U << std::endl;
std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " << sizeof(U) << std::endl
    << std::endl;

std::cout << (int)S << std::endl;
std::cout << "The size in bytes of this variable is: " <<sizeof(S) << std::endl << std::endl;
```

The explanation is so simple: when the type is `char`, `cout` is trying to produce a symbolic output which is `whitespace` for 255 or a pretty-like triangle for 127. When the type is `int`, cout just prints the value of the variable. For example in C:

```
printf("%d", 127) // prints 127
printf("%c", 127) // prints triangle, because %c formatter means symbolic output
```

Comment: This answer couldn't be improved any further than what it already is. Well done!

Comment: Great revision, would it be better to cast it this way: static_cast<int>(VAR), or (int)?

Comment: In your case they're [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx).

Answer (score 0):

They are printed but you cannot see it.
You can open the file of "limits.h":

```
#define CHAR_BIT      8         /* number of bits in a char */
#define SCHAR_MIN   (-128)      /* minimum signed char value */
#define SCHAR_MAX     127       /* maximum signed char value */
#define UCHAR_MAX     0xff      /* maximum unsigned char value */
```

then you look for UCHAR_MAX and CHAR_MAX in the ASCII table,