# Suggestions Code For Time Conversion

Tags: c++

Can someone suggest me how I can convert a variable that contain time in millisec to an exact date?
The code is below:

```
long long SenderTimestamp=System::currentTimeMillis();
```

obviously the time in millisec is in the variable SenderTimestamp

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Vladp  I try to follow the code suggest in the link...but there are some fields that I can't understand like:              boost::posix_time::ptime dt = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(tt);

Comment: @Vladp I think that boost is the name of the struct, so I need to create a new struct to use this kind of format date?

Comment: @Samoth Can you help me to understand how to adapt the solution described in the link above to my case?

Comment: Why don't you just try that `std::time_t tt = static_cast<time_t>(ticksFromEpoch/1000)` ?

Comment: @Samoth Because nothing happens when I add just this line...the value of my variable is in milliseconds yet

Comment: Give us a sample of desired output

Comment: @Samoth  Ok...I have the variable       <SenderTimestamp>    has a millisecond values, but I need to visualize it like a human format, for example    11:35:49:642

Answer (score 1):

In your case this is simpler :

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Comment: Ok but...I need more clarity.... milliseconds means my variable? and how I can set these three values (seconds, minutes, hours) in a single variable?

Comment: +1, but I think it is better to use `static_cast<int>` instead, since the question is tagged `C++`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx