# How to properly static cast a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdarray

I have a code in which at the end of a function I need to cast from int to double all the elements of an array in order to being able to do a final push_back before exiting the function. The code I have right now is:

```
template <class T, size_t dims> class A {
    typedef typename std::array<int, dims> ArrayInt;
    typedef typename std::array<double, dims> ArrayDouble;
    typedef typename std::vector <ArrayDouble> VectorDouble;

/* ...*/

foo() {
   /*  ...*/

   ArrayInt myArrayInt;
   ArrayDouble myArrayDouble;
   VectorDouble myVectorDouble;

    /* Initialize myArrayInt 
    Do some other stuff */

    for (int i = 0; i < dims; ++i) 
        myArrayDouble[i] = static_cast<double>(myArrayInt[i]);

    myVectorDouble.push_back(myArrayDouble);
    }
}
```

It works properly, but I do not feel comfortable about the lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dims; ++i) 
    myArrayDouble[i] = static_cast<double>(myArrayInt[i]);
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: From your title I assume that it's `static_cast<>` that's making you uncomfortable. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)'s a good explanation on `static_cast<>`. In your case the cast is a valid conversion supported by the language. There is no other way to tell C++ to cast a vector (or an array) of `double`s to a vector (or an array) of `int`s than by looping and casting value by value. This is fine.

Comment: which part of these lines do you feel uncomfortable with exactly? The loop, the cast, both? For the loop: look at std::transform. For the cast: this one shouldn't hurt, but something like boost::numeric_cast is a good choice as it takes care of rounding/out of range/...

Comment: Your `for`-loop could probably be simplified to `std::copy(myArrayInt.begin(), myArrayInt.end(), myArrayDouble.begin());`, but otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Did you size your destination?

Comment: I am not happy with the loop. Since both arrays have the same value I was sure there were a way to directly remap memory of something like that. I am looking for an efficient solution.

About the cast, I am using static because I thought it was the most efficient. Since I'm sure that I'm casting always from valid ints to valid doubles, reintrepret_cast or const_cast would be more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function from algorithm.

With [copy_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) :

```
std::copy_n( myArrayInt.begin(), dims, myArrayDouble.begin() );
```

or with [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) :

```
std::copy( myArrayInt.begin(), myArrayInt.end(), myArrayDouble.begin() );
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be written with less code, but it is explicit.

```
ArrayInt myArrayInt;
ArrayDouble myArrayDouble;
VectorDouble myVectorDouble;

/* Initialize myArrayInt 
Do some other stuff */

using std::transform;
using std::copy;
using std::begin;
using std::end;

// with explicit conversion
auto to_double = [](const int i) { return double{i}; };
transform(begin(myArrayInt), end(myArrayInt), begin(myArrayDouble),
    to_double);

// with implicit conversion
copy(begin(myArrayInt), end(myArrayInt), begin(myArrayDouble));
```

Comment: Watch out! You can not push_back into an array.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Apart from what @BЈовић said, I think this answer is a bit complicated for something as simple as I pretend. But thank you anyway!

Comment: It is (a bit complicated), beause technically, you only need the last line (the `copy`).