# How do I use strlen() as int?

Tags: c++

I want to use the numbers that **strlen()** returns in a function that requires an **int** value.

```
functionName((strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

This piece of code doesn't work because they return size_t.

Is there any way to convert that result to int so I can make addition operations and use them as int?

Comment: You can use a `static_cast<int>()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I believe I've asked the question wrong because your solutions don't work. The error I (still) get is _'strlen' was not declared in this scope_. @Cyber

Comment: Use either `#include <string.h>`, or even better `#include <cstring>` and use `std::strlen()`.

Comment: I was using _string_, it works with _cstring_ and with or without static cast.

I just declared it like this using cstring: `int lungimeNumeSiPrenume=strlen(nume)+strlen(prenume)+1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code *does* work, unless your compiler does something very strange or you haven't shown us the actual code.

The only thing that could possibly go wrong is an overflow error (unsigned ints can hold larger values than signed ints). You could check that with `std::numeric_limits<int>` if you really think your strings can become that incredibly large.

Comment: You were right - it does work only not with _string.h_, but with _cstring.h_.

Comment: You mean the other way round, don't you? And if you really use <cstring.h>, replace that with <cstring> or <string.h>, even if your compiler allows <cstring.h>.

Comment: It's without the ".h" (sorry about that), but I am using **c**string.

`#include <cstring>`

Comment: OK... so, the difference between <string.h> and <cstring> (and equivalent cases where C++ uses old C headers) is that the latter puts all names also in namespace std, i.e. will allow you to write "std::strlen" instead of "strlen". At least if your compiler is standards-compliant...

Answer (score 5):

Most of the other answers are using C-style casts which you shouldn't do in C++:
You should [static cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx).

```
functionName( static_cast<int>((strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if you can add the values, then you need to check if you can cast to int, and the you cast..

```
sizt_t size = strlen(word);
if (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()-size >= strlen(otherword))
{
    size += strlen(otherword);
    if (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()-size >= 1))
    {
        size += 1;
        if (size <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        {
            functionName(int(size));
        }
        else
        {
            //failed
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //failed
    }
}
else
{
     //failed
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you want it to be really robust, you should check each individual strlen() result as well... :) Just imagine both word's and otherword's size were std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() ... :)

Comment: A paranoid version :)

Comment: @Vlad: Well, depends on where the input comes from and how important the program is :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have veeery long strings here it is safe to use cast:

```
functionName((int)(strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

if you want you can use `static_cast<int>` but there is no differences now.

```
functionName(static_cast<int>(strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

Comment: C-style casts aren't recommended in [tag:c++].

Comment: C-style strings are also not recommended in c++.

Comment: @Avt: Right, but C-style strings with C-style casts are still worse than C-style strings with C++-style casts.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is internally `unsigned int` on most sensible platforms. Typecast it to `int` and be done with it:

```
functionName(static_cast<int>((strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

or C-style (which is discouraged but legal):

```
functionName((int)((strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));
```

How likely is it that the sum total of those lengths would be over 0x7fffffff (that's the limit of `int` on 32-bit platforms)? Probably not very likely.

Comment: C-style casts aren't recommended in [tag:c++].

Comment: Downvoting for giving working answers isn't recommended, either.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ use `otherWord.length()`:  `functionName( word.length() + otherWord.length() )`.

This is one way to do a `strlen()` of   `functionName((int)(strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord)+1));`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int functionName(int rstr )
{
    return rstr;
}




int main ()
{
    char word[]      = "aaa";
    char otherWord[] = "bbb";

    cout<< "word =  "<<word<<"\n" ;
    cout<< "otherWord =  "<<otherWord<<"\n" ; 

    cout<<  "The sentence entered is   "<<  functionName((int)(strlen(word)+strlen(otherWord) ))<<"   characters long \n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the question was asked for [tag:c++]!