# How to check if a string returned by scanf is null

Tags: c, string, null, compare

I'm reading an input string from the user with `scanf().`

I want to check if this string is NULL (\0) or not.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *argument; // argument for mycat
scanf("%s", &argument);

if(fork()==0)       // at child
{
    printf("Child process: about to execute \"mycat %s\"\n", &argument);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(strcmp(argument, "") == 0) // <-- Here is the problem
    {

        execlp("mycat", "mycat", &argument, NULL);      // execute child process
    }
    execlp("mycat","mycat", NULL);
}
```

I'm compiling with g++ compiler on Red Hat 6.1

**Edit:** The problem is that I'm not able to dereference `argument` either for the `if` statement or even for use with `strlen()`.

Comment: why not use strlen instead, if the length is zero then it would work right?

Comment: without entering text if you press ENTER it will not return the null.. it return the empty string mean length is zero.. so i will also suggest you to check if **strlen** is 0 mean user didn't enter any value.

Comment: `char *argument;` argument is uninitialised; it does not point to anything.

Comment: Alright, apparently my question is written in a wrong way. I was thinking that when the user inputs `"\0"` it will be equivalent to a null string, however `strlen()` returns a length of 2. So I finally used `strcmp(input, "\\0")` to check if user input is equal to `"\0"` and it worked. I'm accepting the first answer because it's more relevant to the question and it's the first one. I apologize for the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` and `\0` are not the same thing, though they both evaluate to zero. `NULL` is a pointer zero, i.e. it's what we use for a null pointer. `\0` is the character with ASCII number zero, otherwise known as `NUL` (one 'L'), i.e. is a `char` with value 0.

There is an important difference between a `char *` being `NULL` (i.e. there not being a string in memory at all), or the string being empty (i.e. only containing one `char` which is `\0` otherwise known as `NUL`).

To test for the first:

```
if (!string)
```

or if you like to be more verbose:

```
if (string == NULL)
```

To test for the second:

```
if (!string[0])
```

or if you like to be more verbose:

```
if (string[0] == 0)
```

Obviously if you need to test for both, test for the first then the second, as the second would dereference a null pointer if `string` was `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference, the second situation is what I want. However, this solution generates a run-time error and the program never enters the 'if' statement.

Comment: @Ameen There are other things wrong with your program, primarily that you have not allocated any memory for your string. Try `char argument[1024];`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

Check [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)'s return value to test whether the operation succeeded, read in something.

For your example it would return `0` if nothing was read, or `EOF` if there was nothing to read from or an error occured.

---

However there are issues with the example code:

1<sup>st</sup> issue:

```
char *argument; // argument for mycat
```

is just a pointer pointing to "somewhere/nowhere". Reading an uninitalised variable invokes undefined behaviour, copying data to "nowhere" also invokes undefined behaviour.

To fix this allocate some memory to it by for example doing:

```
char * argument = malloc(42); /* Allocate 41+1 bytes, that is room for a C-"string" 
                                 being 41 characters long. */
strcpy(argument, ""); /* Initalise it to an emtpy string. */
```

---

2<sup>nd</sup> issue:

```
scanf("%s", &argument);
```

tries to scan data to the **address** of `argument` not where it is pointing to (if it were).

To fix this do

```
scanf("%s", argument);
```

or even better, also tell `scanf()` the size if the buffer to read into, so it won't overflow it. SO assuming the above initialisation, this would be:

```
scanf("%41s", argument); /* Read one less then there is room, as the 42nd char is used to hold the '0'-terminator. */
```

Comment: `char * argument = malloc(42);` gives me a compilation error: `Invalid conversion from void* to char*`.

Comment: @Ameen: This error indicates you are actually not using a C compiler, but a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Ameen you tagged this "C" where casting the return from `malloc` is harmless but frowned upon. In C++ you need to cast the returned value of malloc; I am told the preferred way in C++ to do that is to use `static_cast<>`, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/in-c-why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx

Comment: alk&@abligh  You're right, I was compiling this with g++, it worked fine with gcc thou. I used `strcmp()` to check user input.